# Получение неправильного ответа

Tags: c#

Почему при вводе числа 2 в e_power_enter программа выводит в MessageBox ответ 19, а не 20?
(engine.power типа float)

```
int k;
engine.power = float.Parse(e_power_enter.Text) / 100;            
k = (int)(engine.power * 1000);
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(k));
```

Comment: А какое, собственно, значение в `e_power_enter.Text`, для которого результат 19, а не 20?

Comment: @Regent число два

Comment: Хм. Не могу воспроизвести, а какая у вас версия фреймворка?

Comment: @VladD у меня получилось https://www.screencast.com/t/C81JAg2dwWI

Comment: @VladD .NET Framework 4.7

Comment: @AGS17: Ага и у меня, спасибо. Интересно, что небольшое изменение программы меняет и результат.

Comment: @VladD самое интересное что если вставить промежуточное значение, то все гуд https://www.screencast.com/t/LyCBJ36nmZuu

Comment: @Alex78191: А вот у меня 2017-ая студия выдала 19, что я делаю не так?

Comment: То есть почему так, это понятно. Но непонятно, что влияет на результат.

Comment: Это потому что тип **float** при переводе теряет точность. Попробуйте **double**.

Comment: @Alex78191 вы очень вежливы в данном сообществе

Comment: @Alex78191 https://www.screencast.com/t/C81JAg2dwWI https://www.screencast.com/t/LyCBJ36nmZuu одним и тем же компилятором 2017 студии. Как вы это объясните?

Comment: У меня тоже 19 выводит при таргете 4.5.

Comment: @Alex78191 компилировать научись :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский сорри, я не компилятор

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Дело в том, что float/double в C# (а также в Java, С++ и т. д.) — *двоичные дроби*. Они представлены внутри как набор из целого числа (мантиссы) и степени двойки (порядка). Число 2 может быть представлено в виде двоичной дроби, а вот 0.02 — нет, т. к. оно равно 1/50 (а в знаменателе не только степени двойки). Поэтому число 0.02 не может быть точно представлено в виде `float`.

Что же содержится в переменной `engine.power`? Там содержится двоичная дробь, наиболее близкая к 0.02. Проверим это таким кодом:

```
float enginepower = 2f / 100;
Console.WriteLine(enginepower * 100 - 2);
```

Он выдаёт не 0, как можно было бы ожидать, а -4,470348E-08 (на моей машине).

Это значит, что значение `engine.power` реально немного меньше двух. При умножении на 1000 результат будет немного меньше 20, приведение к `int` отбрасывает дробную часть, и результат получается равным 19.

---

А что нужно делать? Есть несколько вариантов.

1. Вместо неустойчивого к мелким ошибкам отбрасывания дробной части

   ```
   (int)(engine.power * 1000)
   ```

   использовать гораздо более здравое *округление*:

   ```
   (int)Math.Round(engine.power * 1000)
   ```
2. Если вам похожие проблемы встречаются часто, имеет смысл перейти на тип данных `decimal`, в котором числа внутри хранятся как *десятичные*, а не двоичные дроби. Учтите, что операции с этим типом данных медленнее, т. к. нету нативной поддержки процессорами.

---

**Продвинутое расследование**, с копанием в ассемблерном выхлопе и спецификации.

На моей машине вот такой код:

```
float f = 0.02f;
float ff = f * 1000;
int k = (int)(ff);
```

вычисляет в `k` значение 20, а вот такой:

```
float f = 0.02f;
int k = (int)(f * 1000);
```

— 19. (Это в Debug-режиме; в Release-режиме обе версии текста производят один и тот же ассемблерный код и одинаковый результат — 19.) Расследую, почему так.

Произведённый JIT ассемблерный код такой:

```
            ; float f = 0.02f;
mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],3CA3D70Ah   ; 32bit f = 0.02f
            ; float ff = f * 1000;
fld         dword ptr [ebp-40h]             ; extend f to 80bit prec and push
fmul        dword ptr ds:[1453D00h]         ; multiply by 32bit 1000f
fstp        dword ptr [ebp-44h]             ; pop and convert 80bit result to 32 bit -> ff
            ; int k = (int)(ff);
fld         dword ptr [ebp-44h]             ; extend ff to 80bit prec and push
fstp        qword ptr [ebp-50h]             ; pop and convert to 64bit -> double temp
movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [ebp-50h]       ; extend temp to 128bit and copy to xmm0
cvttsd2si   eax,xmm0                        ; truncate to 32bit int eax
mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],eax         ; store to k
```

и

```
            ; float f = 0.02f;
mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],3CA3D70Ah   ; 32bit f = 0.02f
            ; int k = (int)(f * 1000);
fld         dword ptr [ebp-40h]             ; extend f to 80bit prec and push
fmul        dword ptr ds:[1393CF4h]         ; multiply by 32bit 1000f
fstp        qword ptr [ebp-4Ch]             ; pop and convert to 64bit -> double temp
movsd       xmm0,mmword ptr [ebp-4Ch]       ; extend temp to 128bit and copy to xmm0
cvttsd2si   eax,xmm0                        ; truncate to 32bit int eax
mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax         ; store to k
```

Это можно условно записать так:

```
float32 f = 2f / 100;
float80 r1 = f;
r1 *= float32(1000f);
float32 ff = r1;
r1 = ff;              // <-- тут потеря точности
float64 temp = r1;
float128 r2 = temp;
int32 k = (int32)r2;
```

и

```
float32 f = 2f / 100;
float80 r1 = f;
r1 *= float32(1000f);
float64 temp = r1;
float128 r2 = temp;
int32 k = (int32)r2;
```

Разница, как мы видим, в том, что для вычисления промежуточного результата значение `f * 1000` обрезается до 32-битной точности, а потом загружается назад в 80-битный регистр, а оттуда через 64-битное значение загружается в XMM-регистр. Во втором варианте кода сохранение промежуточного результата отсутствует, код не обрезает значение, и до 64 бит обрезается более точное 80-битное значение, что и приводит к разнице в результате.

---

Явное разрешение на такие разные пути вычисления есть в спецификации языка, §4.1.6 Floating Point Types:

> Floating-point operations may be performed with higher precision than the result type of the operation. For example, some hardware architectures support an “extended” or “long double” floating-point type with greater range and precision than the double type, and implicitly perform all floating-point operations using this higher precision type.

Ещё по теме: [Strange behavior when casting a float to int in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8911440/276994) (особенно верхний ответ).

Comment: Эх, если бы вы объяснили, почему при введении доп переменной мы получаем ожидаемое значение... https://www.screencast.com/t/vXjvnhKxG :)

Comment: @AGS17: Ага, вот над этим как раз и бьюсь сейчас :)

Comment: @AGS17 тут дело совсем не во временной переменной. Оптимизации убьют вашу временную переменную. Смотрите: `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString((int)float.Parse("2") / 100f * 1000f));` этот код выведет 20.

Comment: @Nikita: Можно вместо `float.Parse` использовать литералы тоже.

Comment: Вот в [этом ответе](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8911646/3432401) присутствует объяснение таких результатов.

Comment: @Regent: Ага, и правда. Попробую найти это в ассемблерном коде...

Comment: @Regent: Уф, закончил ответ.

Comment: @VladD в итоге можно сказать так. Первое правило: нигде не использовать прямое приведение дробного числа к int. Второе правило: никогда нигде не использовать прямое приведение дробного числа к int. Ещё можно припомнить разные результаты между `double d1 = 6.2f * 10;` и `float f = 6.2f; double d2 = f * 10;`.

Comment: @Regent: Угу, у truncate смысла довольно мало, т. к. ошибки округления/представления могут легко привести из `>= n` в `< n`.