# Талантливые начинающие криптографы

Tags: алгоритм, криптография, любой-язык, соревнование, казаки-разбойники

Подача ответов на конкурс завершена! Промежуточные итоги будут скоро подведены, окончательные итоги — после завершения параллельного конкурса взломщиков. Спасибо всем, кто принимал участие!

---

Итак, мы проводим очередное соревнование! Это соревнование необычное, оно состоит из двух частей. Тема задания — проверка пароля.

Мы ведь все помним, что краткость — сестра таланта? Первая часть задания состоит в разработке **как можно более короткой** функции, проверяющей пароль. На вход функция должна получать строку в идиоматичном для выбранного вами языка виде (`char*` или `wchar_t*` для C, то же или `std::string`/`std::wstring` для C++ и т. д.), на выход выдавать логическое значение (снова-таки в принятой в вашем языке форме, например, `int` в C и `bool` в C++). Логическое значение «истина» соответствует тому, что введённая строка является правильным паролем.

Пароль придумываете вы сами, и должны будете раскрыть его в конце конкурса. Длина вашего пароля не должна превышать 64 символов (code point'ов для unicode-строк), но функция должна уметь обрабатывать строки разумно произвольной длины (помещающиеся в половину доступной виртуальной памяти). Если ваша функция выдаёт `true` и для других строк, ничего страшного, все они тоже считаются подходящими паролями.

**Оцениваться** будет длина этой функции в символах за вычетом синтаксически незначимых пробелов, причём идентификатор тоже считается одной буквой, при условии, что замена этого идентификатора на однобуквенный во всех местах, где он ссылается на ту же сущность, не поменяла бы смысл программы. Также ключевые слова языка считаются за один символ.

Почему же это задание сложное? Почему тривиальная функция `() => true` не подходит? Дело в том, что **в ход игры вмешиваются игроки второй части вопроса** — начинающие талантливые хакеры. Любой из хакеров может попытаться *взломать* вашу функцию: подобрать такую строку (возможно, длиннее 64 символов и не обязательно совпадающую с задуманным вами паролем), что ваша функция вернёт на ней `true`. Взломанные функции выбывают из конкурса. Править вашу функцию после того, как опубликован взлом, нельзя. Править вашу функцию более чем через сутки после опубликования нельзя. Но вы можете написать альтернативную функцию отдельным ответом, не более трёх в общей сложности на одного участника. Красть чужие функции нехорошо. Хакерам будет дано 3 дня на взлом каждой их ваших функций.

С одной стороны, вам следует создавать не слишком сложную функцию, чтобы она не проиграла по длине другим, а с другой стороны, не слишком и простую, чтобы хакеры не смогли её так просто взломать.

**Ограничения**: Функция не должна содержать [undefined behaviour](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (если оно есть в вашем языке/компиляторе), предполагать стабильность или нестабильность вычислений с плавающей точкой, полагаться на случайные числа или текущие дату/время/информацию из внешних источников (включая обращение к сторонним сервисам, в том числе и в интернете). Функция должна быть *детерминистической*, то есть, менять свой результат лишь при изменении входных данных, и данные должны передаваться в неё лишь через входной параметр. Функция не должна пользоваться библиотеками кроме стандартных библиотек языка, и ни в коем случае не должна пользоваться сторонними крипто-, хэширующими и математическими библиотеками (или отдельными функциями/процедурами/методами/...). Функция не должна также обращаться к специальным криптографическим конструкциям, встроенным в оборудование ([пример](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5_%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b_%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4_AES)). Функция не должна запускать сторонних процессов (кроме возможно копий/частей программы). Функция должна на вашем пароле на вашем компьютере выдавать положительный результат за не более чем минуту вычислений. Функция имеет право упасть, это также считается положительным ответом. То есть, если хакер сможет «положить» вашу функцию, она считается взломанной. (Но он не может передавать в функцию испорченную строку: `nullptr`, невалидную память, или например содержащую встроенные нули для C. Другими словами: хакер не должен использовать UB или рефлексию сам.)

Если для компиляции вашей программы нужны нестандартные ключи, их полная длина в символах добавляется к количеству символов функции.

При неоднозначности лучше переспросите в [code golf-чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39121/code-golf-----). Окончательное решение при отсутствии консенсуса остаётся за организатором конкурса.

**Продолжительность конкурса** — одна неделя, а точнее, окончание в 23:59:59 29.05.2017 по UTC. Новые решения после этого срока в зачёт не принимаются. Время окончания конкурса хакеров равно времени окончания конкурса криптографов плюс трое суток; взломанные *после* этого срока функции считаются выдержавшими испытание. Вы должны будете предоставить пароль после окончания конкурса хакеров. Если ваша функция не выдаёт истину или падает на *вашем* пароле, она снимается с конкурса.

**Победителем конкурса** будет объявлена самая короткая невзломанная программа, которая выдержит проверку «своего» пароля.

**Языки** для конкурсных программ допускаются лишь те, для которых есть общедоступный компилятор под общедоступные платформы (одна из: Windows XP+, Linux не более, чем пятилетней свежести, Mac OS). Просьба не злоупотреблять экзотическими языками. В ответ желательно включить полную компилируемую программу, будет учитываться лишь длина  функции проверки (а также ваших функций, вызываемых из неё).

Конкурс хакеров [проходит здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/669462/10105).

Обсуждение вопроса ведётся в [code golf-чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39121/code-golf-----), если вам непонятно условие, спрашивайте там (ну в крайнем случае в комментариях, если у вас недостаточно репутации).

Удачи всем участникам!

---

Турнирная таблица:

```css
#leadership { border-collapse: collapse; } #leadership td, #leadership th { padding: 5px; } #leadership th { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vladd/bd3338bbfa8163530e63717f2305a4d1/raw/4be1307d8a82bf7ea1f961cda9e90cde59e75eaf/ruso-winnertable-669381-v2.js"></script>
<h1>Таблица лидеров</h1><table id="leadership"><tr><th></th><th>Автор</th><th>Язык</th><th>Ток.</th><th>Взлом?</th><th>Осталось</th><th>Хор?</th><th></th></tr></table>
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, что взломщик видит исходник функции и зашитый в нее результат для сравнения "правильного" пароля и должен опубликовать этот пароль в текстовом виде?

Comment: @avp взломщик видит исходник функции и чтобы "взломать" её, он должен предоставить аргумент, при котором функция вернёт условный `true` (или упадёт).

Comment: @avp: Да, исходник виден вместе со всеми данными.

Comment: То есть я правильно понял, что надо написать функцию, которую взломщик не сможет развернуть и выудить из нее исходный пароль или положить ее?

Comment: @AlexKrass: Именно так! Да ещё и короткую при этом.

Comment: А можно написать на ассемблере (и исказить control-flow, чтобы не декомпилировалось в Си)? :)

Comment: @Андрей **PWND!** ?

Comment: @Андрей: Да, всё будет добавлено :)

Comment: @VladD можно взглянуть на скрипт, который считает токены?

Comment: @pank: Скрипта как такового нет. Я копирую текст в файл, убираю инклюды, заголовки функций и функции, не имеющие отношения к проверке, поиском/заменой с ручным контролем заменяю каждый идентификатор/ключевое слово на однобуквенное (контроль нужен, чтобы не попасть внутрь строк, например), и натравливаю на файл `File.ReadLines(@"path").Select(l => l.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\t", "")).Sum(l => l.Length)`.

Comment: @VladD а стандартными хеширующими библиотеками пользоваться можно?

Comment: @Alex78191: Нет, конечно! Об этом прямо сказано в разделе «Ограничения».

Comment: @VladD, а можно извратится и написать что-нибудь на T-SQL =D? И как оценивается длинна? Ведь в одном языке есть короткий синтаксический сахар, например LINQ, а другие должны перебирать циклами.

Comment: @iluxa1810: Конечно можно! Длина считается в символах, но (1) незначащие пробелы не считаются, и (2) каждый идентификатор или ключевое слово считается за один символ (за исключением случаев, когда из их имени что-то вытягивается).

Comment: Конкурсы - лишнее, тем более прошедшие.

Comment: @zb': Ну участвовать-то никто не заставляет...

Comment: @VladD ну давайте ещё и конкурс песен-плясок на комповые темы проведем, тоже никто не заставляет участвовать. по мне все эти конкурсы жуткий неформат.

Comment: @zb': [Это формат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2933/10105). Чтобы сделать гольф неформатом, есть один законный путь — на Мету.

Comment: гольф это даже не не формат, это вообще бессмысленное занятие, есть спецсайты для такого типа codefight и прочего.

Comment: @zb': Неконструктивно. Если вы хотите отменить принятое коллективно решение о нужности гольфа, добро пожаловать на Мету.

Comment: Я просто высказываю свое мнение, или у вас это тоже стало запрещено? Мнение простое - бардак а не вопросы/ответы, один перетаскивает вопросы с инглиша, сам на них отвечает, сам принимает, сам с этого прется. Другой конкурсы из дегенератских собеседований транслирует. Третий ноет про все это. Праздник самолюбования какой-то. А ещё тут стали тыкать в грубой форме почти все.

Comment: @zb': То, что мы с вами сейчас обсуждаем, не имеет отношения к вопросу. Поэтому в этих комментариях такое обсуждение точно оффтопик. Если вы хотите поговорить о том, что ru.SO стал хуже, приходите в чат. Если у вас есть конкретные предложения по улучшению, приходите на Мету. Но здесь этому обсуждению точно не место.

Comment: Так это и не вопрос, вот в чем дело.

Comment: @zb' вы можете оставить свой голос "против" на Мете в [обсуждении](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2933/178779). Если отрицательный ответ будет лидировать - вопросы-соревнования появляться перестанут. Но в данный момент разрешение соревнований лидирует с разгромным счетом - 44/7.

Comment: Песни-пляски тоже многие поддержут.

Comment: @zb': Демократия же.

Comment: @PavelMayorov три последних кодгольфа - это "кто вручную напишет любую популярную хэшфункцию", "как отсорировать массив символов" и "как в вашем языке записывается деление с остатком".

Comment: @PavelMayorov если и проводить такое - то надо как-то ограничивать темы. А то скоро дойдет до "как развернуть строку"

Comment: @PashaPash: Это, кстати, [не так уж и просто](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/). Неинтересные вопросы должны просто минусоваться, никакого отличия от остальной разрешённой тематики нет.

Comment: @VladD я знаю, что это непросто :), но вы вот посмотрите на решения в вопросе по сортировке - там вообще никто не учитывает акценты. заменили ё на е, всего делов. Да, неинтересные вопросы должны минусоваться - но при этом на вопросе про сортировку символов 8 плюсов - хотя, будь он задан без метки соревнования, скорее всего насобирал бы минусов. По какой-то неизвестной причине это "просто" не срабатывает.

Comment: @PashaPash давайте все-таки обсуждать такие вопросы на мете?

Answer (score 13):

## Python 3.2+, 172 токена (время на взлом истекло)

```
def check(p):
    i=lambda x:int.from_bytes(x.encode('utf-16le','surrogatepass'),'big')
    try:return i(p)**65537%i('쳞\ue7e2䄝\uf03a듌垴ﮍ믚騾갢䳡︪ۡ䓽㒞䇑⮚⯎사᳀ᗦ딵㎹勤ㅵᕛ\uda35竹彽㝼꤅熎')==i('꼬㶳ꖅ慘钽\uf0fe젬\uf4fcᆎ횹鸝ᝄ幎垡륿ᖽﮠ鹰\uec89ᮒ핪篜Ⱃ⏾≅刳ﬖ睘쁽뭊㧇읚')
    except:return False
```

Ответ:

```
>>> check('簅䊆蓐鷃礤匹崚콂퉾횏練\ue611ﯻ⁼\uec77酢툖ᒆ뻉쇓\ufbcf')
True
```

Алгоритм - возведение в степень по модулю, как в RSA. Пароль - выхлоп `os.urandom`.

Использование `decode` с `'surrogatepass'` позволяет преобразовать практически любой набор байт в строку. Помогает уменьшить количество токенов.

Comment: Так, погодите. Значит, [синус использовать нельзя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669444/178779) - а длинное возведение в степень - это типа нормально?!

Comment: @Abyx: Время на взлом истекло, опубликуете пароль (и комментарии к алгоритму, если можно)?

Answer (score 11):

## C#, 96 токенов (снята с участия автором)

Простая небезопасная хэш-функция, очень известный алгоритм вычисления хэша.

```
public bool check(string str)
{
    ulong hash = 14695981039346656037;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
         hash = (hash ^ (byte) str[i]) * 0x100000001b3;
    return hash==7512177054858691173;
}
```

**Ответ:**  4354351213674675880334221324354351213-rsa

В данном алгоритме очень тяжело найти колиззии на подобных ключах из-за большого доступного пространства и относительно равномерного распределения, хоть данный алгоритм и не является криптографический безопасным.

**UPDATE**

Я думал, что данный алгоритм все-таки взломают, но данный алгоритм подтвердил свою надежность при простых операциях xor и умножения, но к сожалению, этот алгоритм написан не мною, а другими учеными и называется данный алгоритм FNV1a. Хоть жесткого ограничения на участие чужих алгоритмов не было, но не хочется выигрывать чужими наработками, поэтому я снимаю с участия этот алгоритм.

Comment: Для уточнения. Максимальное значение для ulong 18446744073709551615 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF). hash = 14695981039346656037 (0xCBF29CE484222325). Возьмём для примера, что строка состоит из 1 символа, тогда hash ^ str[i] изменит максимум 3 последние цифры. Само число так и останется большим. Если его умножить на 0x100000001b3, то не будет ли это считаться переполнением (UB)?

Comment: @Vitaly: В C# нет UB, переполнение просто возвращает результат по модулю размера результата.

Comment: @Vitaly Спасибо за вопрос и спасибо VladD за ответ! :) Я разверну чуть подробнее ответ и скажу, что да это будет считаться переполнением потому что выходит за рамки, но это не UB..я под этот алгоритм я не просто так выбрал C#. В C# без операции checked { }, по умолчанию переполнение превращает максимальное число в минимальное без ошибки. Предположим ulong.MaxValue + 1 будет равно ulong.MinValue, т.е. 0, +2 == 1 и т.д. Это поведение определенно и везде одинаково в C#.

Comment: За 24 часа удалось посчитать последний символ пароля, а их тут, как минимум, 10. Да уж, в 72 часа не уложиться.

Comment: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669462/%d0%a2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b/671264#671264)

@Firepro. "Хотя заменить в этом алгоритме одно число на другое, и он уже не FNV)". Заменишь и количество коллизий значительно увеличится. Но я сомневаюсь, что это сильно поможет его взломать. Без брутфорса не обойтись, переполнение то никуда не девается.

Comment: @xirbm Указанный алгоритм, как я написал в исходном сообщении действительно известный, более точное название ему FNV1a. Вставил я его сюда, лишь потому что он легко запоминается, кроме чисел конечно и иногда его использую. Я не вижу в конкурсе ограничения на использование существующих алгоритмов, а уже выкладывали DJBHash, RC4, и т.д. Если сообщество или организатор посчитает это нечестным/неверным, я готов снять этот вариант с конкурса, просто в конкурсе нет четких правил насчет возможности использования сущ.алгоритмов и набора операций. Мне не принципиально :) P.S Ваша ссылка недоступна

Comment: @Firepro: Это моя вина, я должен был лучше указать, что ожидаются свои алгоритмы, а не уже существующие. В любом случае, ваш ответ валиден, не вижу причин снимать его с конкурса.

Comment: @VladD Хочется все-таки победить собственными силами, а здесь же победа не моя, а победа трех великих ученых. Я лишь в течении дня искал в этом алгоритме коллизии на цифрах, но не смог найти (я думаю, что они тоже это делали) и решил, что это будет отличная головоломка для всех и кто-нибудь его взломает, но я так понимаю, что не нашел никто и этот простой алгоритм оказался для всех сложнее, чем я думал. Я поступлю честно по отношению к другим участникам, и сниму эту функцию с участия. Я думаю, этот пост подскажет многим участникам, на чем основываться при написании функций :)

Comment: @Firepro, функция, конечно, жесть - я попался (и крепко влип - зато допилил генератор коллизий для Бернштейна так, что он выдает по несколько коллизий в секунду и если в PHP djb все еще используется, то самое время отказаться) на ее видимую простоту, никакими мыслимыми способами не вышло подобрать коллизию. Не то, чтобы подобрать - даже как-то приблизиться в угадывании 1 символа, к облегчению перебора, исключения каких-либо вариантов. полный голяк. Не надо сниматься, классная функция

Comment: @m9_psy У нее очень хорошее равномерное распределение, но я еще после дня анализа, выбирал такой ключ, в котором вероятность коллизий минимальна на этой функции. FNV1a дает минимум коллизий на числах. Если этой функции добавить еще какой-то дополнительный этап увеличивающий время вычисления, ей наверное цены не будет. Просто, если выигрываешь чужой наработкой (а я щас на 1 месте), то победа совершенно не чувствуется, поэтому не вижу смысла продолжать участие этой функции в конкурсе, но она действительно хороша :)

Comment: @Firepro: Большое спасибо за вашу принципиальность!

Comment: Я смог найти лишь конечный хеш `1379955394597465991` к которому надо придти. Но восстановить цепочку и из диапазона `14695981039346656000 - 14695981039346656255` попасть в диапазон `1379955394597465856 - 1379955394597466111` уже не смог. Не настолько сильно подкован в математике, но спасибо, открыл для себя [модулярную арифметику](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Система_остаточных_классов) и [китайскую теорему об остатках](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Китайская_теорема_об_остатках).

Comment: Извините конечно, но мне кажется вы не совсем понимаете о чем говорите. У хеш-функций есть три критерия по которым их оценивают: 
1. Стойкость к восстановлению прообраза
2. Стойкость к коллизиям первого рода
3. Стойкость к коллизиям второго рода
Эти критерии зависимы, то есть:
если не выполняется критерий 1, то не выполняются также критерии 2 и 3
если не выполняется критерий 2, то не выполняется критерий 3
От нас требуется доказать, что для хеш-функции не выполняется критерий 1, хотя всему миру известно что для данной хеш-функции доказано лишь невыполнение критерия 3.

Comment: "FNV1a дает минимум коллизий на числах." Вы об этом где-то прочли? Или сделали вывод из своих вычислений?

@Alex Krass "Я смог найти лишь конечный хеш 1379955394597465991 к которому надо придти." Можно поинтересоваться, что вы назвали конечным хешем?

"За 24 часа удалось посчитать последний символ пароля, а их тут, как минимум, 10. Да уж, в 72 часа не уложиться." Также очень интересное заявление, подкрепить вычислениями сможете?

Comment: @xirbm, очевидно число, которое при умножении на 0x100000001b3 даст необходимый остаток 7512177054858691173 в ulong. Отсюда получаю диапазон, попав в который, мы можем подобрать последний символ пароля если идти с конца цепочки.

Comment: @xirbm Общую диаграмму распределений и сравнений вы можете найти на англоязычных порталах, а также самостоятельно провести вычисления с данной функцией. Вот один из примеров поиска колизий на данной функции: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed 

Вы говорите про свойства криптографических хеш-функций, хотя я не раз упоминал, что она таковой не является. Просто поиск коллизии может занять продолжительное время при использовании статического анализа и т.д.

Comment: А теперь немножко о наших шансах. Так как обратимость этой хеш-функции не была доказана, нам остается лишь полный перебор.
Количество всевозможных хешей: 2(64) - 2 в степени 64, что примерно равно 1.8*10(19). Я за выходные (3.65 дня) перебрал 32*10(10) различных входных данных, то есть мои шансы были 17.7*10(-7)% (мне не фартануло)

Comment: @Alex Krass, Задумка неплохая, тоже этим занимался. Жаль только что к успеху это привело бы лишь в случае когда задуманный пароль был бы короче 3 или 4-х символов

Comment: @Firepro Я говорю про свойства хеш-функций, а криптографической она становится, когда все три этих свойства выполняются. Да, эта функция не криптографическая потому что существует алгоритм по которому можно найти коллизии второго рода за доступное время. Жаль только что мы не коллизии ищем.

Answer (score 9):

## C, 73 токена (взломан)

x86, little-endian

```
int f(char* s) {
    uint32_t a = 0, b, i = 0;
    if (s[0] && s[1] && s[2])
        a = *(uint32_t*)s;
    b = a;
    while (++i)
        a = a * 7 + 7;
    return a + b == 980355503;
}
```

---

Взломан @Mike, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669554/10105).

Comment: `while (++i)` — UB? Знаковое переполнение же, писали в чате. Да и размерность `int`-а может быть разной (привет x64!); как результат — платформозависимое количество итераций.

Comment: И ещё: вы проверяете первые три символа, но считываете в `a` четыре (и снова `int`...). Так планировалось, или вы забыли в условии `... && !s[3]`?

Comment: @Arhad, `s[3]` не забыл.

Comment: little / big indian?

Comment: @Arhad §6.2.5/9 - A computation involving unsigned operands can never overﬂow, а проверять s[3] нет смысла - там ноль обязан быть в крайнем случае.

Comment: @Qwertiy точно indian (, но вроде не обязано же везде работать?

Comment: Например, на MIPS (или ARM/ARC с выключенным unaligned) запросто можно уронить, если передать `s` на невыровненный на 4 адрес.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, то есть получается, что пароль должен быть не короче трёх символов (я в начале подумал, что строго три и пропущена проверка на нуль-терминатор).

Comment: @Arhad, почему? Неправильный пароль может быть любой длины.

Comment: @avp вроде не требовалось кроссплатформенность по условиям. А в языке такого ограничения нет.

Comment: **Взлом** Например пароль `z(!3` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669462/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B/669554#669554

Comment: @VladimirGamalian `... can never overﬂow` — То есть `(unsigned)UINT_MAX + 1U != 0U`?

Comment: @Arhad не понял, честно говоря, о чем это сравнение говорит?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, стандарт (упомянутый вами §6.2.5/9) же говорит об отсутствии переполнения при операциях с участием беззнаковых целых, так? Вот я и привёл контрпример в виде вопроса. Мол, получается, что прибавление единицы к `UINT_MAX` не вызывает тогда переполнения?

Comment: @Arhad понял, нет, не вызовет, т.к. в таком случае, согласно тому же стандарту, будет взят модуль, который в вашем примере как раз будет равен нулю.

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3, 100 токенов (взломан)

```
def check(s):
  try:
    return int(s[:32], 16) * int(s[32:], 16) == 0x116a53fdcf374e3d8a4a19ca59a8017fd3680e7b707f9ed834a8ac4538586845
  except:
    return False
```

---

Взломан @Firepro, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670176/10105).

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3, 107 токенов  (взломан)

Исправил уязвимость предыдущего [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669994/198501).

```
def check(s):
  try:
    x = int(s[:32], 16)
    return x > 1 and x * int(s[32:], 16) == 0x620fe07bca360829f97c33bd0aa64795a27c2cc4f67dd5d699a0af7cccb86d1f
  except:
    return False
```

---

Взломан @Firepro, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670468/207618).

Answer (score 9):

## C, 180 токенов (взломан)

```
/*
 * gcc crypt.c -o crypt
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define M 0x2B72576B913FD740
#define S 0xB72576B913FD7400

typedef unsigned char uchar;

int check(uchar * pwd) {
    ulong s = M, i, j, k;
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(pwd); i < j; i++) for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) s = k & 0xC ? (i[pwd] & (1 << k) ? s ^ i[pwd] : s >> 1) : (*(pwd + i) & k ? s << 2 : s ^ S);
    return s == 0x0832CB347454C8AF;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s string\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int s = strlen(argv[1]);
    uchar * pwd = calloc(s + 1, sizeof(char));
    memcpy(pwd, argv[1], s);
    printf("Result: %s\n", check(pwd) ? "OK" : "FAIL");
    free(pwd);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Взломан @Mike, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/671029/10105).

Comment: Эй, это уже ваш 4й ответ! По правилам же только 3 ответа допускаются.

Comment: Один из ответов (не подошедших по критериям) удалил. Если нужно, могу, так же, заменить вариант, который не подошёл. А что касается, "не более 3 ответов", то этот пункт, видимо, я упустил. Условия, действительно, длинные.

Answer (score 8):

## C++, 59 токенов (взломан)

Пусть будет c++ из-за `bool` :)

```
bool check(const char *str)
{
    uint64_t h = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        h = ((h << 5) + h) + c;

    return h == 1180004904744509286;
}
```

---

Взломан @m9_psy, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669513/10105).

Comment: Тривиальный Бернштейн (оно же `DJBHash`) в 64-бит упаковке наверное тоже не будет взломан нашими хакерами.

Comment: @alexolut: А какая разрядность вашего `unsigned long`? А то на системах, где `1180004904744509286` в него не влезает, будет всегда false.

Comment: @VladD уточнил тип.

Comment: Возможный (не умею в C) ответ - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669513/189819

Answer (score 8):

## Javascript, 858 токенов (время на взлом истекло)

Ну-ну, попробуйте взломать! :-)

```js
function hash(str) {
  var 
    e32 = 0x100000000,
    f = (x,y,z) => x&y|~x&z,
    g = (x,y,z) => (x&y|x&z|y&z) + 0x5A827999,
    h = (x,y,z) => (x^y^z) + 0x6ED9EBA1,
    sf = [3,7,11,19],
    sg = [3,5,9,13],
    sh = [3,9,11,15],
    pf = [0,8,4,12,2,10,6,14,1,9,5,13,3,11,7,15],
    pg = [0,4,8,12,1,5,9,13,2,6,10,14,3,7,11,15],
    ph = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
    rot = (x,s) => ((x << s | x >>> (32-s)) + e32) % e32,

    a = 0x01234567,
    b = 0x89abcdef,
    c = 0xfedcba98,
    d = 0x76543210,
    i, j,
    data = [...str].map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))

  data.push(0x80)
  while(data.length % 16 != 14) data.push(0)

  data.push((str.length * 32) % e32)
  data.push(Math.floor((str.length * 32) / e32) % e32)

  for (var j=0; j<data.length; j+=16) {
    const [aa,bb,cc,dd] = [a,b,c,d]
    for (var i=0; i<16; i++) {
      [a, b, c, d] = [d, rot((a + data[j+pf[i]] + f(b,c,d))%e32, sf[i%4]), b, c]
    }
    for (var i=0; i<16; i++) {
      [a, b, c, d] = [d, rot((a + data[j+pg[i]] + g(b,c,d))%e32, sg[i%4]), b, c]
    }
    for (var i=0; i<16; i++) {
      [a, b, c, d] = [d, rot((a + data[j+ph[i]] + h(b,c,d))%e32, sh[i%4]), b, c]
    }
    [a,b,c,d] = [(a+aa)%e32, (b+bb)%e32, (c+cc)%e32, (d+dd)%e32]
  }

  return [a,b,c,d].map(x => [4,0,12,8,20,16,28,24].map(y => ((x >> y) & 15).toString(16)).join("")).join("")
}

function check(str) {
    return hash(str) == "7eaf037aa05ffa6f5a0844d8f891570f";
}

console.log(check("Это был почти md4 :-)"));
```

Comment: Функция не должна пользоваться библиотеками кроме стандартных библиотек языка, и ни в коем случае не должна пользоваться крипто-, хэширующими и **математическими библиотеками** (или отдельными функциями/процедурами/методами/...).

Comment: @Alex78191: ну самописными-то можно... Уточню-ка я условие.

Comment: @Danis в смысле - как?

Answer (score 8):

## C#, 294 токена (время на взлом истекло)

№2 (вторая попытка)

```
public bool check(string pass) 
{
    try 
    {
        string subfind = string.Concat((char)1, (char)3, (char)17, pass.Substring(58, 5));

        return string.Join("", pass.Take(58).Select(p =>
        {
            int rand = p * 2017 % pass[63];
            var sv = new List<int>();

            var q = from sub in subfind where sub <= rand select sub;
            while(q.Any())
            {
                sv.Add(q.Max());
                rand -= q.Max();
                if (sv.Count > 8) break;
            }

            var regroup = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < subfind.Length; i++)
            {
                regroup += sv.Contains(subfind[i]) ? "1" : "0";
            }

            return (char)regroup.Select(pq => pq == '0' ? 0 : 1).Aggregate((a, b) => a * 2 + b);
        })) == "nulla molestie ligula mauris dictum sed pellentesque ipsum";
    }
    catch { return false; }
}
```

#### Взлом функции

Поскольку за отведенное время функция не была взломана, я публикую решение. Данная функция реализовывает слегка модифицированную [ранцевую криптосистему Меркла-Хеллмана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0). В общем-то обладая одним только этим знанием можно уже самому успешно осуществить взлом, без моего решения. Поэтому алгоритм я не называл, это было бы слишком просто. Если хотите сами немного подумать и найти ответ, дальше не читайте))

Само решение:

Криптосистема основана на закрытом ключе и двух взаимно простых чисел. Это все данные, которые нужны для расшифровки сообщения и находятся они в неявном виде в самой функции.

Сравнивая описание алгоритма в той же вики и код, находим следующее. Зашифрованной строкой является `"nulla molestie ligula mauris dictum sed pellentesque ipsum"`, часть закрытого ключа передается в строке следующих пяти символах `pass.Substring(58, 5)`. Одно из чисел находится в позиции `pass[63]`, второе вычисляется как обратный элемент по модулю `pass[63]` для числа `2017`.

Все, что остается сделать, это перешифровать сообщение и скормить нашей функции. Выбираем закрытый ключ, не трогая первые три значения, к примеру

```
int[] w = new int[] { 1, 3, 17, 47, 233, 578, 3077, 9672 };
```

Выбираем число `q` так, что бы оно было больше суммы значений `w`.

```
int q = 14832;
```

Проверяем, что для него существует обратный элемент, это будет наш r.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var inverse = Inverse(2017, 14832);
}

private static int Inverse(int a, int m)
{
    int x, y;
    int g = GCD(a, m, out x, out y);
    if (g != 1)
        throw new ArgumentException();
    return (x % m + m) % m;
}

private static int GCD(int a, int b, out int x, out int y)
{
    if (a == 0)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
        return b;
    }
    int x1, y1;
    int d = GCD(b % a, a, out x1, out y1);
    x = y1 - (b / a) * x1;
    y = x1;
    return d;
}
```

Получили `r = 9361`

Ну а дальше остается только перешифровать.

```
static string alternative(string pass) 
    {
        int[] w = new int[] { 1, 3, 17, 47, 233, 578, 3077, 9672 };
        int q = 14832;
        int r = 9361;

        int[] b = new int[] { 
            w[0] * r % q, 
            w[1] * r % q, 
            w[2] * r % q, 
            w[3] * r % q, 
            w[4] * r % q, 
            w[5] * r % q, 
            w[6] * r % q, 
            w[7] * r % q };

        string passbits = string.Join("", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass).Select(byt => Convert.ToString(byt, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));

        var a = Regex.Split(passbits, @"(.{8})").Where(p => p != "").Select(p =>
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                sum += Convert.ToInt32(p[i].ToString(), 2) * b[i];
            return (char)sum;
        });

        return string.Join("", a) + string.Join("", w.Skip(3).Take(5).Select(p => (char)p).Union(new List<char>() { (char)q })); 
    }
```

И скормить ответы нашей функции, у меня в основном вышли иероглифы на различных значениях ключей и чисел.

```
check("辄왝轏轏燌⩁ꌗꍌ轏鿮顰늕瓵鿮⩁轏瓵ꀣ왝轏燌⩁ꌗ燌왝蒨瓵顰⩁谦瓵爁늕왝ꌗ⩁顰鿮谦⩁葳鿮轏轏鿮辄늕鿮顰頻왝鿮⩁瓵葳顰왝ꌗ/éɂఅ◈㧰");
check("仐䵵㮅㮅⳵၏䢧寲㮅䑒䥣䁓ㅊ䑒၏㮅ㅊ垝䵵㮅⳵၏䢧⳵䵵㱁ㅊ䥣၏㜰ㅊ䁀䁓䵵䢧၏䥣䑒㜰၏⣶䑒㮅㮅䑒仐䁓䑒䥣㘘䵵䑒၏ㅊ⣶䥣䵵䢧GãȳЉ࿗៟");
check("윙찆铌铌蟣⩁뺫铌陥ꈧ뀩陥⩁铌뀩좲찆铌蟣⩁뺫蟣찆엲뀩⩁沆뀩먰ꈧ찆뺫⩁陥沆⩁鎥陥铌铌陥윙ꈧ陥분찆陥⩁뀩鎥찆뺫1̦ϒࠝ✏㧰");
```

Comment: _"Длина вашего пароля не должна превышать 64 символов"_ vs `pass[66]`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, не заметил ошибку, извиняюсь, уменьшил длину пароля до нужного ограничения.

Answer (score 8):

## C#, 37 токенов (взломан)

Честно говоря, когда разбираешь функцию, хочется побольше коротких функций связанных с интересными комбинациями побитовых операций, арифметических действий, а не модифицированные алгоритмы типа SHA-1 и алгоритмы с проблемой факторизации на 100 разрядных числах, взлом которых **очевидно** невозможен за ближайшую жизнь в этом мире нулей и единиц.

Вот разминочка для мозга :)

```
public static bool check(string str)
{       
   int hash = 0;
   foreach(var c in str) hash ^= (hash * 23) + c;
   return hash==766862343;
}
```

---

Взломан @AlexKrass,  [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670662/16416).

Comment: Функция [взломана простым перебором значений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670662/16416)

Answer (score 8):

## C#, 109 токенов

Зарядка для хвоста.

```cs
public static bool check(string str)
{
    ulong hash = 0;
    int l = str.Length, a = l / 2;
    string str1 = str.Substring(0, a), str2 = str.Substring(a, l- a);
    foreach (var c in str1)
        foreach (var i in str2)
            hash ^= ~hash * 198349 + (ulong)(i%(c+1));
    return hash == 16396813230762036365;
}
```

Ответ: mа$t3rсгу

Answer (score 8):

## C++, 69 токенов (время на взлом истекло)

```
auto check(std::string s) {
    auto h = 6508530148971001438ull;
    for (uint8_t c : s)
        h = (h * 14886173955864302971ull) ^ c;
    return !h;
}
```

Вариация на тему FNV-0 64-bit.

Firepro [свой FNV1a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669753/177684) с конкурса снял, поэтому мы это исправим новым ответом!

Пароль это конечно же 8 (почти) случайных байт. Успешного перебора!

---

Ответ: `check("@\t!\xfbTD-\x18")`

---

#### Как это работает:

Берем заготовку пароля

```
>>> struct.pack("d", math.pi)
b'\x18-DT\xfb!\t@'
```

и прогоняем ее через FNV0

```
auto fnv0(std::string const& s) {
    uint64_t h = 0;
    for (uint8_t c : s) {
        h = (h ^ c) * 0x100000001b3;
    }
    return h;
}

fnv0("\x18-DT\xfb!\t@") == 6508530148971001438
```

Считаем число обратное к 0x100000001b3 (modular multiplicative inverse):

```
>>> pow(0x100000001b3 , 2**63-1, 2**64)
14886173955864302971
>>> 14886173955864302971 * 0x100000001b3 % 2**64
1
```

меняем порядок операций, и получаем функцию `check`.
Пароль при этом тоже разворачивается и становится `@\t!\xfbTD-\x18`.

---

#### Как это ломать:

TL;DR: перебором за несколько минут.

Перепишем функцию `check()` как

```
h0 = 6508530148971001438;
h1 = (h0 * 14886173955864302971) ^ s[0];
...
h8 = (h7 * 14886173955864302971) ^ s[7]
return h8 == 0;
```

Заметим, что `h7` равно `s[7] * 0x100000001b3`, и у этого числа много нулей, например `0x0000ff000001b14d` для `s[7] == 0xff`. Это позволяет ускорить перебор, не делая вычисление h8.

Получаем вот такую функцию OpenCL:

```
kernel void func(uint s0, global uint* result) {
  size_t i = get_global_id(0);
  if (i >= 256*256) return;
  ulong h0 = 6508530148971001438ul;
  ulong h1 = (h0 * 14886173955864302971ul) ^ s0;
  ulong h2 = (h1 * 14886173955864302971ul) ^ (i >> 8) & 0xFF;
  ulong h3 = (h2 * 14886173955864302971ul) ^ (i & 0xFF);
  for (unsigned s3 = 0; s3 != 256; ++s3) {
    const ulong h4 = (h3 * 14886173955864302971ul) ^ s3;
    for (unsigned s4 = 0; s4 != 256; ++s4) {
      const ulong h5 = (h4 * 14886173955864302971ul) ^ s4;
      for (unsigned s5 = 0; s5 != 256; ++s5) {
        ulong h6 = (h5 * 14886173955864302971ul) ^ s5;
        ulong h7 = h6 * 14886173955864302971ul;
        if ((h7 & 0xffff00fffff00000ul) == 0) {
          result[i] = (s3 << 16) | (s4 << 8) | s5;
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

У меня она выполняется примерно 6 секунд, это позволяет дойти до `s0 == '@'` за минуты.

Comment: Ну и зачем ещё одно умножение-и-xor? Скучно же. И изобрели FNV ведь не вы? Какая доблесть в публикации алгоритма, придуманного умными дядьками?

Comment: Никого не смущает !h??? Есть сомнения что автор сам не знает правильный ответ))

Comment: А можно пару ссылок на оригинальный FNV-0 или лучше код, а то я гуглить не умею.

Comment: @Abyx, Не особо шарю в С, но мне кажется алгоритм ответа чуть-чуть привязан к знанию ответа. Не вижу s6 в func. Получи строку str для "своей" хеш-функции, где h0=FNV0(str) = 424578851499022793

Comment: @Abyx, А видео карта какая?

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 321 токен (время на взлом истекло)

```
# coding: utf-8
import copy

MY_PASSWROD = "0106BD6DE78317D077D1720060D29970D51809E09442410459450453"

pk = "Lorem ipsum blah-blah ключ"

a = 256


def MAGIC(k):
    b = range(a)
    j = 0
    for i in range(a):
        j = (j + b[i] + k[i % len(k)]) % a
        b[i], b[j] = b[j], b[i]

    x = 0
    y = 0
    c = map(int, (" ".join([str(c) for c in copy.deepcopy(b)]).split(" ")))
    while True:
        x = (x + 1) % a
        y = (y + c[x]) % a
        c[x], c[y] = c[y], c[x]

        K = c[(c[x] + c[y]) % a]
        yield K


def test_U(s):
    if not s:
        s = pk
    s = [ord(c) for c in s]
    m = MAGIC(s)
    answer = ""
    for c in pk:
        answer += "%02X" % (ord(c) ^ m.next())
    return answer == MY_PASSWROD

# Вне конкурса, пример использования
def tester(target_string):
    ans = test_U(target_string)
    if ans:
        print "WIN"
    else:
        print "LOSE"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Давай, перебери меня
    tester("")
    tester("yolo")
    tester("ЮНИКОД")
    tester("*"*2**28)
```

Это RC4. Ответ - `\x00Я люблю тортики. ڝڞ Хочу тортик.∰™`. Лишнее барахло (лишний юникод в префиксе/суффиксе) - исключить какой-нибудь хитрый подбор по словарю.

Comment: Ну и зачем было вставлять строку `c = map(int, (" ".join([str(c) for c in copy.deepcopy(b)]).split(" ")))`? Она как-то улучшает RC4? :-)

Comment: Если это известный алгоритм, то стоит хотя бы упомянуть об этом в условии.

Comment: @VladD, это действительно RC4, отпираться бесполезно. В неизвестности алгоритма большая доля интереса. Одно дело написать - это RSA прямо (тоже в вопросах есть), а другое дело оставить код без пояснений, чтобы кто-нибудь неискушенный (вроде меня) позарился на небольшой размер кода и размял мозги. В ходе разминаний я на практике понял, почему с RSA взятки гладки. Если написать, что используется RSA, то никто и пробовать не станет - известно, что алгоритм сложно поддается "взлому" и останется пытать разлчиные вырожденные для атаки случаи.

Comment: @m9_psy: Ну с одной стороны конечно да, можно считать это одним из шагов взлома. С другой стороны интересно же разгадывать шифр своего коллеги, а не мировых спецов по криптографии? Ну и если верить википедии, то у вас ARC4.

Comment: @m9_psy попробуй взломай AES 2048 бит. RC4 взломаешь?

Comment: Самое интересное, что при начальном анализе зависимостей я обнаружил, что строки скажем "a", "aa", "aaaaa" дают одинаковый хеш. т.е. если строка целиком из однаковых символов то хеш равен хешу одной буквы. Но потом при малейших других изменениях я увидел, что кардинально меняются все биты

Answer (score 7):

## C#, 74 токена (взломан)

Ответ № 1. Попробуем что-нибудь совсем простое, язык C#.

```
public static bool check(string p)
{
    try
    {
        int n = -977;
        foreach(var c in p)
            n += p.Aggregate((_, __) => (char)(_ + __));

        return p.Substring(12, 5) == (n / 2).ToString() ? true : false; 
    } catch { return false; }
}
```

---

Взломан @Firepro, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669489/10105).

Comment: ihackyourkey28411alex!bba - это изи же :)

Comment: @Firepro ссылку на **взлом** забыли: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669489/178779

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby 1.9.2+, 205 токенов (взломан)

```
def g_c(password)
  r = []; password.chars.sort{|a,b| r << a; a.ord - b.ord}
  r.join
end

def m_p
'MS__Myyyp_rreepMS_uuuuuaossassdrrq11___draaaaoossMMMS__eeeeppprruuuuy0788-08500555-0222277887477277725524423355233344477-0001255555555577788001111MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM'
end

def check(password)
  g_c(password) == m_p
end
```

---

**Уточнённая версия, не зависящая от реализации сортировки в конкретном руби:**

```
class Array 
   def partition3
      a = Array.new(3) {|i| []}
      each do |x|
         a[yield(x)].push x
      end
      a
   end

   def qsort(&block)
      return self.dup if size <=1
      c,l,r = partition3 {|x| block.call(first,x)}
      l.qsort(&block) + c +  r.qsort(&block)
   end
end

def g_c(password)
  r = []; 
  password.chars.to_a.qsort{|a,b| r << ((r.size % 4 == 0 ) ? a : b); a.ord <=> b.ord}
  r.join
end

def check(password)
  g_c(password) == 'My_EMtraMFixMPasMordM(83M199M32EE-(8E619E132-(83-199-3288619813236113211199yyxtry_ixyPasyord_xtr__ix_Pas_ordxtraxxasxordtraitssotdrarassrrdaaaodiodss'
end
```

---

Взломан @VladD, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670762/10105).

Comment: Думаю не особо зависит. Точнее на тех данных которые есть он будет однозначно один и тот же. не зависимо от версии

Comment: Исходя из описания этой функции в реализации руби. Могу добавить конкретную реализацию конечно, хотя сути это не изменит.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-sort

Comment: Так там же с реализацией документация

Comment: Плюс, это функция языка всё же, а не какая-то сторонняя библиотека.

Comment: А какие описания нужны?

Comment: для строки **'Hello, world!'** текущий ruby [генерирует](https://ideone.com/UIhDXE) `eHollHHelw rdll oooow,,,Heelloo`, в то же время IronRuby генерирует `ello,,,,,      woorrlllllddddddddd!!!!!!!!!!!!`

Comment: Так что поведение алгоритма зависит от версии интерпретатора. Так не годится.

Comment: А для python2.x И python 3.x различия тоже должны учитываться например? Это версия языка а не версия интерпретатора. В руби можно так же написать что в версии 2.0.x и в версии 2.3.x один и тот же код будут работать по разному. Если, конечно это проблема, могу встроить функцию сортировки явно и самопально, хотя это из разряда 'моя программа для виндовс не запускается на linux'

Comment: Python 2 и 3 - это именно что разные версии языка. У них разный синтаксис.

Comment: IronRuby maintains compatible versions with Ruby 1.8.6 and Ruby 1.9; IronRuby 1.0 and IronRuby 1.1.3, respectively. If you're not sure which version to use, use IronRuby 1.1.3, but only if you do not need Ruby 1.8.6 compatibility. Давайте просто решим что тут ruby 2.0.0

Comment: @Чад думаю, достаточно просто условие добавить в ответ, для которого эта ф-ия работоспособна. Вроде не требуется кроссплатформености/кроссверсионности.

Comment: @Чад сегодня мы решим, что там ruby 2.0.0 - а завтра IronRuby обновят чтобы 2.0.0 тоже поддерживалось.

Comment: Я думаю когда обновят, результаты будут одинаковые

Comment: @Чад на каком основании вы так думаете?

Comment: @Чад с чего бы двум совершенно разным реализациям использовать один алгоритм сортировки?

Comment: @Чад: Не, ну это и правда не по правилам. Нельзя опираться на подробности конкретной реализации языка. Это implementation defined behaviour, оно имеет право поменяться в другой версии. Конкретная версия языка и конкретный компилятор — это как-то слишком, как мне кажется.

Comment: @VladD У Ruby нет соблюдаемой спецификации, де-факто референсной реализацией является MRI/CRuby. Альтернативные реализации, в т. ч. IronRuby, отклоняются от референсной то там, то сям, но это их проблемы. Поэтому ограничиться MRI, тем более 2.0+ (более старые версии уже безнадёжно устарели) очень даже разумно и я не вижу в этом большой проблемы. У этого кода есть проблема посерьёзнее: зависимость от кодировки строки, кодировка литералов зависит от системы. Но это можно починить.

Comment: @Чад: Ага, вот так уже намного лучше, спасибо!

Comment: @D-side: А как починить?

Comment: @Чад: Я правильно понимаю, что теперь версию Руби можно просто указывать как 2+?

Comment: @VladD да, можно даже 1.9.2+ на ней тоже проверил на всякий случай

Comment: @VladD `.encode("UTF-8")`, в нужных местах, к примеру.

Comment: @D-side: Тогда может быть договоритесь с ТС по этому поводу, а? А то я в Руби ни уха ни рыла не смыслю.

Comment: @Чад: А у вас точно нет ошибки копипаста в кодовом слове?

Comment: @VladD точно нет, сделал копи паст с сайта - всё работает

Answer (score 7):

## Java, 393 токена (время на взлом истекло)

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution
{
    public static boolean check(String pwd)
    {
        String chk = "176230078174140160185101136122101089205201025138070243083056221017027225235135030144152073240059092027236208249148115073214246072102240160193049088024192124080088214163068";
        if ( ( pwd == null ) || ( pwd.length() * 3 != chk.length() ) ) return false;

        int n = pwd.length();
        char[] src = pwd.toCharArray();
        int[] res = new int[n];

        Arrays.fill(res, 0);

        for ( int i = 0; i < n*4; ++i )
            for ( int j = 0; j < n*4; ++j )
                res[(i+j)/8] ^= ((src[i/8] >> (i % 8)) & (src[n/2 + j/8] >> (j % 8)) & 1) << ((i+j) % 8);

        for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
            if ( res[i] != Integer.parseInt(chk.substring(i*3, i*3 + 3)) )
                return false;

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(check((new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine()));
    }
}
```

## Пароль:

```
// конечно, есть и другие варианты, способные пройти проверку
System.out.println(check("Do you really believe yourself to be a master of fencing?"));
```

## О решении:

Разобравшись с тем, что делает функция, нетрудно составить уравнения (в булевой алгебре) для каждого бита зашитого в функцию большого числа (переменными будут биты строки-пароля).
Каждое полученное уравнение будет являться, помимо всего прочего, полиномом Жегалкина.
Полностью раскрывать алгоритм не буду, но напомню для наводки одно из свойств "исключающего или": `~X = X ^ 1`
P.S.: аккуратно реализованный алгоритм решения отрабатывает за считанные секунды и выдаёт все варианты пароля

Answer (score 7):

## C/C++, 222 токена (время на взлом истекло)

Little-endian 256-bit hash на основе широко известного 32-bit Murmur

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

static inline void
step (uint32_t *h, uint8_t c) // MurmurOAAT
{
  (*h) ^= c;
  (*h) *= 0x5bd1e995;
  (*h) ^= ((*h) >> 15);
}

// 256-bit hash
int
pass (const char *p)
{
  uint32_t hash[8] = {0};
  uint64_t res[4] = {0x56ba9b8ecd0060fd, 0xbb746d2bb6e93110,
                     0x15313f6bdc32584e, 0xca5267ffc8a1e4b4};
  
  if (p && *p) {
    int i, j = 0, l = strlen(p);
    uint8_t *d = (uint8_t *)p;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++, j++)
      step(hash + j % 8, d[i % l] + i + l);
  }

  return memcmp(hash, res, sizeof(hash));
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int endian = 1;
  printf("%s-endian\n", *((char *)&endian) ? "little" : "big");
  
  return puts(pass(av[1]) == 0 ? "Guess" : "Fail") == EOF;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, 189 токенов

Ну, теперь не взломаете!

```
def i(x):
    y = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        y += ord(x[i]) * 0xFFFF ** i
    return y

def c(s):
  try:
    x = i(s[:32])
    return x > 1 and x * i(s[32:]) == i('锼ԯ獆湳巩樋ꬁ옃\uf35e꺕䍔\udc02嗉旋ꗶ\uf723㇉랎\ue3d0\uea64像㪡ώ浑㤥\udd93僉䆦햲\udd7b\ud93b㻜叕䕎ꩠ陋컲襦캹ꃷ宊\uf14e욏肪\ude3a艎㒗Ģ또ሎ婢翈蚱ႉΑ桔ᅅ凹ᡎ哨朤뽝ꚜ鐔')
  except:
    return False
```

Вам надо разложить это число на множители (309 цифр):

```
103885866244747381663615014343439738509398529989572625404989988315137697040223344857852085986157148263429988190803798673714482791480965400051780365963630448634611947249214382745760025418403983231982081656737500352492523151600463727256295721224125884702295398456027019890543321464255995380923386472902008862899
```

Comment: Кто же знал, что тут такие внимательные и находчивые взломщики :)

Answer (score 6):

## C/C++, 104 токена (не подходит)

С/C++ little-endian

```
/*
  Compile: g++ passcr.c 
  Test:    ./a.out [password-to-guess]
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

// Returns 0 - false, 1 - OK
int
pass (const char *p)
{
  double hash[2] = {2.87, 3.62};
  uint64_t result[2] = {0xc037bb81ea8b2770, 0x3fc8e0d99aef179d};

  while (p && *p) 
    hash[0] -= (hash[1] += ((hash[1] * hash[0]) / ((double)(*p++))));

  return memcmp(hash, result, sizeof(hash));
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int endian = 1;
  printf("%s-endian\n", *((char *)&endian) ? "little" : "big");

  return puts(pass(av[1]) == 0 ? "Guess" : "Fail") == EOF;
}
```

Comment: Математику ж мы запретили?

Comment: @VladD, в условиях так много букв, что запрет на libm я проглядел. Завтра поправлю на что-нибудь просто перемешивающее битики.

Comment: @VladD, как править, чтобы подходил? Просто отредактировать код в вопросе, чтобы собиралось без `-lm` (выбросить `sin()`)?

Comment: Да, например, так. Хотя если убрать синус, то не всё равно будет неправильно по правилу «Функция не должна полагаться на ... нестабильность вычислений с плавающей точкой». Т. к. сложение `double`'ов в языке не определено строго и зависит от опций оптимизатора, например.

Comment: @VladD, ОК, поправил. Что же касается "нестабильности с плавающей точкой", то это, конечно, платформозависимая штука, что-то вроде пресловутого UB, только пуристы еще не сделали ее столь же ... (ладно, догадайтесь об остальных словах сами).

Comment: Боюсь, всё достаточно кисло. Загляните [вот сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/668871/10105), в часть под названием «продвинутое расследование»; там шарп, но стандарт разрешает в C++ (и наверное в C) то же самое ради эффективности.

Comment: @VladD, почел, разве из этого следует, что один и тот же код на той же платформе при разных запусках будет перемешивать битики по разному? Imho, нет. Мы имеем оборудование и используем его в своих целях (а вот вызов библиотечных функций, согласен, это в данном случае *не спортивно*)

Comment: @VladD, сутки от опубликования первого варианта (одно из ваших правил) истекают, так каково решение? Вердикт **(не подходит)** остается?

Comment: Именно так, один и тот же код, в зависимости от того, куда его заинлайнил оптимизатор и решил ли он в этот раз выкинуть промежуточную переменную или нет, может произвести разный результат. Ну и кроме того, мы ж хотим, чтобы хакеры смотря на код могли предугадать, что он делает на _вашей_ машине? А с плавучей нестабильностью у них этой возможности нет.

Comment: Боюсь, что остаётся :-( Я вот [ещё один ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669698/10105) закрыл по той же причине: он полагался на конкретный метод сортировки в конкретной имплементации.

Comment: Значит это *правильный* (в смысле противостояния взлому) код. Хотя, мне кажется, без синуса он должен ломаться. Посмотрим (вне конкурса) сломает кто или не по зубам.

Comment: Нет, мне он кажется _неправильным_ в том смысле, что перенеся на другую машину исходники, нас не гарантированно пустят по правильному паролю. А это уже плохо.

Comment: @VladD, кстати, а `random()` использовать по правилам?

Comment: Тоже запрещено, причём явно: «Функция не должна содержать undefined behaviour (если оно есть в вашем языке/компиляторе), предполагать стабильность или нестабильность вычислений с плавающей точкой, **полагаться на случайные числа** или текущие дату/время/информацию из внешних источников (включая обращение к сторонним сервисам, в том числе и в интернете).»

Comment: @VladD, с каких пор   `(srandom(password[0]), random())` (кстати, random же стандартная часть libc) стало не *псевдослучайным* (и абсолютно детерминированным), а **случайным** числом? Вообще, довольно странные правила.

Comment: Ну, тут вопрос в том, чтобы поведение алгоритма на разных машинах было гарантированно одинаковым. Для того, чтобы на машине хакера правильный пароль **гарантировано** выдавал `true`. Если вы посмотрите все криптографические алгоритмы, у них нигде нету ничего implementation-defined, по той же самой причине.

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы хакеры взламывали **видимый им** алгоритм, а не пытались раскопать невидимый, и только потом его взламывали. Этот конкурс — алгоритмический, а не на дизассемблирование libc с машины автора вопроса.

Answer (score 6):

## C, 144 токена (взломан)

```
/*
 * gcc crypt.c -o crypt
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SI sizeof(UINT)
#define SC sizeof(char)

typedef unsigned int UINT;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef const char * CSTR;

UINT check(CSTR pwd) {
    UINT m[] = {0xB38F0E32, 0x8639E96A, 0x35B6E758, 0}, s = m[2], t, * c;
    while (*pwd) {
        c = m;
        t = *((UINT *)pwd);
        while (*c) t ^= *c++;
        s ^= t;
        s = s << 8 | s >> ((SI << 3) - 8);
        pwd += SI;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s string\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }
    UINT s = strlen(argv[1]), a = s % SI ? 1 : 0;
    char * pwd = calloc(s / SI * (SI + a) + 1, SC); // to prevent segfault
    memcpy(pwd, argv[1], s);
    printf("Result: %s\n", check(pwd) == 0x7720AEAA ? "OK" : "FAIL");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Взломан @pavel, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669967/10105).

Answer (score 6):

## C/C++, 391 токен (время на взлом истекло)

Классика на хешировании

```
bool crypt(char *s){
    int i;
    long long m[3][9] = {1000000009LL,
                  1000000000013LL,
                    1000000000039LL,
                    999999999989LL,
                    100000000019LL,
                    100000000003LL,
                    1000000000000001LL,
                    1000000000000003LL,
                    1000000000000009LL,
                    994324858,
                  410165024251LL,
                  882143347009LL,
                  450913810178LL,
                  75177384683LL,
                  52035486628LL,
                  536516625723718LL,
                  167996437453997LL,
                  860362117327470LL };
    for (;*s;s++)
        for (i=9;~--i;)
            m[2][i] = (m[2][i] * 37 + *s)%m[0][i];
    bool r = 1;
    for (i=9;~--i;)
        r &= m[1][i]==m[2][i];
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Точная длина считается так: общее количество чимволов, но идентификаторы и ключевые слова схлопываются в 1 символ, и пробелы/концы строк не считаются.

Comment: По этой причине переменные можно называть длинно. А можно и не называть.

Comment: @VladD у вас скрипт есть или вы руками?)

Comment: Замены идентификаторов просматриваю в полуавтоматическом режиме, т. к. могут быть строки, подсчёт непробельных символов скриптом.

Answer (score 6):

## C, 301 токен (взломан)

Версия 3.

Как и обещал - работа со строками.

```
/*
 * gcc crypt.c -o crypt
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

int check(uchar * pwd) {
    uchar * a = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~";
    int d = strlen(a), i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(pwd); i < j; i++) {
        if (strchr(a, pwd[i]) == NULL) pwd[i] = a[pwd[i] % d];
        if (i > 0) pwd[i - 1] = a[(((pwd[i - 1] ^ pwd[i]) << 1) * pwd[i]) % d];
    }
    return !strcmp(pwd, "Tp9?k=HDN&nD{9 ~JzUYG3h>lF {`> K<% pm~J>y E=2B=y+<x+nf@*%kDZ;z/'WYbWOk'usw>Z");
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s string\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    int s = strlen(argv[1]);
    uchar * pwd = calloc(s + 1, sizeof(char));
    memcpy(pwd, argv[1], s);
    printf("Result: %s\n", check(pwd) ? "OK" : "FAIL");
    free(pwd);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Взломан @Mike, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/671216/671216).

Comment: У вас функция не возвращается `bool`/`int`, исправляйте.

Comment: Упс, упустил. Поправил.

Comment: **Взлом**: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669462/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B/671216#671216

Answer (score 6):

## C, 57 токенов (взломан)

Довольно простой алгоритм.

```
int f(wchar_t* s)
{
    uint64_t h = 0;
    if (wcslen(s) < 60) return 0;
    for (uint64_t i = 1; *s++; h += *s*i + *(s-1) * i, i++);
    return h == 0x75F00B5;
}
```

---

Взломан @pank, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670868/10105).

Comment: Не умею в С, но `*(s-1)` - это не неопределенное поведение? При первой итерации

Comment: @Андрей, нет такого на итерации. Там пустое тело цикла.

Comment: @Андрей, в данном случае - нет. Строка начинает считываться со второго символа, т.к. `*s++`.

Comment: @Андрей, длина пароля неважна. `*(s-1)` - это предыдущий символ, по отношению к текущему.

Comment: `"\uF152\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\uFFFF\u7001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001"`

Comment: @Андрей, если это ответ, то он не подходит.

Comment: Видимо неправильно перевел ф-ю в C#. Увы.

Answer (score 6):

## C, 584 токена (<del>870</del>)

В основе один известный алгоритм (надеюсь, что не ошибся в его реализации :D). Пароль найти очень легко, он сразу же вытекает из определения алгоритма.

```
#include <string.h>

#define m(x, y) (x < y ? x : y)

int check(char *s)
{
    int S[64] =
        {226, 70,158,126,107, 48,154, 93,168,  8,222,222,131,241, 67,  3,
         162,176, 96,197,113,101, 76,128,139, 18, 88,137,192,232,134, 34,
         108, 16,232, 71,108,233, 79,  8,241,123,200,130,  5,190,136, 27,
         164,107,  9,255,192,  8,239,125,249, 29,242, 88,216, 17,157,191};
    int A[65] = {0}, B[65], C[65] = {0}, *a = A, *b = B, *c = C, l = strlen(s), *t, i, j, k;
    char m, n, p, q;
    for (i = 0; i < 65; ++i)
        B[i] = i;
    for (i = 1, m = 0; i <= 64; ++i, m = p, t = c, c = b, b = a, a = t) {
        for (j = 1, n = 0, p = S[i-1], *a = *b + 1; j <= m(l, 64); ++j, n = q) {
            q = s[j-1];
            k = q != p;
            a[j] = m(b[j] + 1, m(a[j-1] + 1, b[j-1] + k));
            if (p == n && q == m)
                a[j] = m(a[j], c[j-2] + k);
        }
    }
    return b[l] == 8;
}
```

Comment: Эхм. Напомню, что это как бы гольф, и смыслом является минимальное, а не максимальное количество токенов.

Answer (score 6):

## С++, 64 токена (взломан)

Вот еще один алгоритм, шуточный. Будет смешно, если его так и не взломают...

```
#define rot(x) ((x) << 7 | (x) >> 25)

auto check(char* str) {
    auto h = 0;
    for (; *str; str++)
        h = rot(h * 123456789) ^ *str;
    return h == -77;
}
```

---

Взломан @xirbm, [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/672522/10105).

---

Эх, просто нашли коллизии без всякого криптоанализа. Ну да, простой перебор тут тоже должен работать, только причина тут вовсе не в разрядности типа `int`.

Обратите внимание на вот это выражение: `(x) >> 25`. Что здесь происходит? А здесь происходит знаковый сдвиг вправо на 25 разряда. Поэтому реальная энтропия внутреннего состояния алгоритма - 7 бит вместо 32х. Неудивительно, что так быстро нашлись коллизии :-)

Comment: Зачем нужен криптоанализ в таких шуточных вещах? Если вы желаете его провести, то я могу помочь. Ибо ваше утверждение про 7 бит неверное. Прийти вам нужно не к 2(7), а к 2(6)+2(31)

P.S. n(k)= n в степени k. Если бы энтропия была 7 бит, мы бы с большой вероятностью могли подобрать ответ из одного символа

Comment: @xirbm и этот символ имеет код -77 на системах, где символы - знаковые.

Comment: @xirbm если же рассматривать только ASCII-символы, то первый символ нужен чтобы получить отрицательное число на втором шаге.

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, 277 токенов

```
f n
    | mod (2^n) 0x9fdb8b8a004544f0045f1737d0ba2e0b274cdf1a9f588218fb435316a16e374171fd19d8d8f37c39bf863fd60e3e300680a3030c6e4c3757d08f70e6aa871033 == 0x8c8050e78c71ebd1f5237b68c329213e6110eb4b8658354e8091838043047edc6d3a0fbec9461258fb75bd6a0601e1dc60c0187e9da40a784a972fb452abb2a1 = True
    | otherwise = False

main = do
         s <- getLine
         let n = read s :: Int
         print (f n) >> main
```

Comment: Ну опять стандартные алгоритмы из учебника, ну сколько можно?

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2.7, ~207 токен (время на взлом истекло)

```
r = []

def gc_sort(a, b):
  global r
  r.append((b,a)[len(r) % 4 == 0])
  return (1,(-1,0)[a<b])[a>b]

def g_c(password):
  global r
  r = []
  list(password).sort(gc_sort)
  return ''.join(r)

def check(password):
  return g_c(password) == "yyMySMS_u_u_epeureSMaPS_sruespreoposwyosrpp_dao__So_TSeshoh_a_ernhh__STe9PMe&P9d7M&93S9&3aP763aP1&3a437659365_7311_701&_xsuwx_pswu_reada(10&*61(*_5033_4213_wuww"
```

**Пароль:** My_SuperPassowrd_Than_9&73614510xwe(*32w

Алгоритм в реализации руби был взломан. Хотя, мне кажется, если там бы был использован не qsort для сортировки, было бы не так просто. Но, на мой взгляд, идея получилась интересная.