# Талантливые начинающие хакеры

Tags: любой-язык, соревнование, казаки-разбойники

Итак, мы поводим очередное соревнование! Это соревнование необычное, оно состоит из двух частей. Тема задания — проверка пароля.

В [первой части соревнования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/669381/10105) участники придумывают функцию, которая берёт строку и возвращает результат, является ли эта строка паролем (да/нет). Здесь у нас вторая часть соревнования: **взлом**.

**Ваша цель** — придумать (или вычислить!) пароль, на котором функция из первой части соревнования возвратит истинное значение. Или упадёт.

Пароль не обязательно должен совпадать с тем, который задумал автор функции. Вы можете воспользоваться информацией о том, что авторский пароль не длиннее 64 символов.

Учтите, что автор имеет право править свой ответ в течение суток после его публикации. Публикация взломов для каждого вопроса принимается лишь в первые  72 часа после публикации вопроса.

При публикации ответа публикуйте, пожалуйста, ссылку на него во взламываемом вопросе. (Лучше прямо в вопросе, а не в комментарии, и правьте заголовок, как в других взломанных вопросах.)

**Ограничения**: Строка, которую вы подаёте на вход, должна быть валидной строкой для вашего языка. Например, она не может располагаться в невалидной памяти, и вы не можете использовать рефлексию, чтобы «сломать» внутреннее представление строки и заставить функцию «упасть» на ней. Если алгоритм принимает на вход юникодную строку, ваша строка также должна быть юникодной. Она *может быть* достаточно большой (скажем, размером в `MAXINT`), но не занимать более половины свободной памяти (чтобы не создавать проблем для работы алгоритма одним своим присутствием в памяти). Процесс программного «составления» строки, если он необходим для вашего ответа, должен занимать не более 1 минуты на вашем компьютере, и не приводить к UB. Взлом не должен пытаться вмешиваться в работу функции (например, портить её код или код используемых библиотек, менять память пароля после передачи его в функцию и т. п.).

Если взламываемая функция выбывает из конкурса по той или иной причине, её взломы выбывают вместе с ней. Если ваш пароль при проверке не заставляет функцию выдать истинное значение или упасть, он также выбывает из конкурса. Из нескольких взломов одной функции засчитывается только первый по дате последней правки. Взламывать свои собственные функции нельзя. (Участник должен быть зарегистрирован до времени публикации функции.)

**Победителем** является взлом, не выбывший из конкурса и набравший наибольшее количество голосов.

Если вы использовали какой-то интересный приём для нахождения подходящего пароля, расскажите о нём в ответе! Это наверняка прибавит вам голосов.

**Срок окончания конкурса** — 72 часа после окончания конкурса криптографов, то есть, 23:59:59 1.06.2017. Не забудьте, что каждый отдельный вопрос можно взламывать всего три дня, так что если, например, в последний день конкурса криптографов не будет опубликовано ни одной функции, то в последний день конкурса хакеров нельзя будет публиковать взломы тоже. Удачный взлом может выбыть из конкурса, если взламываемая функция будет удалена из конкурса.

Обсуждение вопроса ведётся в [code golf-чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39121/code-golf-----), если вам непонятно условие, спрашивайте там (ну в крайнем случае в комментариях, если у вас недостаточно репутации).

Удачи всем участникам!

Comment: WTF? Ничего не понял, что это? Не уверен, что такой вопрос относится к тематике сайта...

Comment: @Barmaley: Это же code golf! [Относится](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2933/10105).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Взлом [алгоритма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669381/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8B/669994#669994) представленного pank**

```
def check(s):
  try:
    return int(s[:32], 16) * int(s[32:], 16) == 0x116a53fdcf374e3d8a4a19ca59a8017fd3680e7b707f9ed834a8ac4538586845
  except:
    return False
```

Очень простой свиду, но к сожалению очень сложный алгоритм основанный на проблеме разложения больших чисел на множители. Все отлично знают, проблема разложения большого числа на множители это очень сложная задача, которая не решается быстро, а тут аж 76-ти значное число.

### 1. Общий способ взлома

Нам известно, что одно число может быть до 32 символов, а второе сколько угодно. Я пытался найти 2 множителя случайным способом, но у меня ничего не выходило (**что не удивительно**). Максимум, что я смог получить, что при передаче параметра:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111708946551217595118393411775077160869888185470
```

Выходило почти похожее число:

**787718390241772353770457527863504200469636993**3875734065358324759903345757170

А  исходное в десятичной системе выглядит вот так:

7877183902417723537704575278635042004696369934776381519304816946969514108997

Так себе результат :)

**Естественно**, искать и подбирать 2 таких больших множителя я могу очень-очень долго, поэтому я решил поискать проблему непосредственно в коде.

Ниже, я приведу случай, что вас не спасет даже самый крутой алгоритм от взлома, если вы не учитываете все возможные варианты ввода данных.

### 2. Анализ исходного кода и поиск уязвимости

После недолго анализа я начал разбирать конструкции кода, и увидел, что

**s[:32]** - получить все символы до 32 элемента строки

**s[32:]** - взять все что после 32 элемента строки

Идем дальше, видим следующее:

```
int(s[:32], 16) * int(s[32:], 16)
```

Это означает умножить 2 числа в шестнадцатеричной системе счисления. Следовательно, туда нужно передать 2 числа в шестнадцатеричной системе, ок.

### 3. Уязвимость

Получается, что я могу подставить число 1 и подставить в эту строку тот ключ который нужно получить.

**Берем 2 строки:**

1. 00000000000000000000000000000001
2. 0x116a53fdcf374e3d8a4a19ca59a8017fd3680e7b707f9ed834a8ac4538586845

**Конкатенируем и получаем:**

000000000000000000000000000000010x116a53fdcf374e3d8a4a19ca59a8017fd3680e7b707f9ed834a8ac4538586845

Подставляем в функцию, и она вернула **True**! Это победа :)

Comment: Великолепно :-)

Comment: @Abyx можете продолжить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670228/198501

Answer (score 14):

**Взлом алгоритма №1 представленного Alex Krass:**

```
public static bool check(string p)
{
    try
    {
        int n = -977;
        foreach(var c in p)
            n += p.Aggregate((_, __) => (char)(_ + __));

        return p.Substring(12, 5) == (n / 2).ToString() ? true : false; 
    } catch { return false; }
}
```

**Уязвимость:**

Это простой алгоритм. Весь смысл функции, что она делает сумму символов в строке [ANSI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245259(v=vs.60).aspx) (a==97, b==98 и т.д) добавляя их к изначальной сумме -997, умножает это число на количество символов, а потом делит на 2. После чего что она берет 5 символов начиная с 12 символа в введенной строке и сравнивает с полученным числом.

Получается нужна строка минимум 17 символов в которой с 12 по 17 символ будет число, а также в которой сумма всех символов деленная на 2 будет равна этому числу. Зная алгоритм, мы спокойно можем подобрать строку несложной математикой.

Предположим у нас получилась строка: *ihackyourkey28411alex!bba*, сумма символов равна **2312**:

105+104+97+99+107+121+111+117+114+107+101+121+50+56+52+49+49+97+108+101+120+33+98+98+97

Умножаем на 25 символов строки и получаем 57 800, вычитаем 977 и получаем 56 823. Далее делим на 2 и получаем 28 411.5, округляем до int и получаем 28 411.

Взломали! Функция возвращает **true**

**Решение - любой из ключей:**

```
ihackyourkey28411alex!bba
sdfsdfsdfsdf43531degdfgdfgdfb06
```

Comment: Так сутки еще не прошли: `Учтите, что автор имеет право править свой ответ в течение суток после его публикации.`

Comment: @m9_psy Это второе из условий, функцию можно править, пока функцию не взломали вроде как :)

Comment: Точно, перечитал правила, с почином

Answer (score 12):

**Взлом [алгоритма №2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670228/216352) от pank**

Алгоритм основанный на проблеме факторизации больших чисел.

```
def check(s):
  try:
    x = int(s[:32], 16)
    return x > 1 and x * int(s[32:], 16) == 0x620fe07bca360829f97c33bd0aa64795a27c2cc4f67dd5d699a0af7cccb86d1f
  except:
    return False
```

В прошлый раз мы с вами взламывали алгоритм через уязвимость, в этот раз господин **pank** нам все закрыл...Теперь придется ломать через вычислительные мощности. Найти вручную два простых множителя точно не получится...**но у нас есть кое-что поинтереснее!**

Для начала учитываем, что число которое нужно получить, в десятичной системе счисления выглядит так:

```
44354711195682213318901868940731534954425938156569080174424467380253591366943
```

Смотрим и печалимся.. **что разделить на 2 не получится без остатка...**

Проведем краткий анализ и на основе кода программы предположим, что 77-значное число имеет всего два простых множителя,  размером 39 знаков или 32 знака в hex. @Abyx еще не успел начать брутить множители, поэтому это сделаю я :)

### Как разложить-то?

Далее, окунемся в теорию вычислительной сложности и оценим примерно сколько же нам нужно времени в 2017 году, чтобы разложить 77 значное число на простые множители. Честно говоря, немного, ведь 100 значное число уже разложили в 1991 году на [RSA Factoring Challenge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_Factoring_Challenge).

На старом 2200 MHz Athlon 64 это [потребовало бы 4 часа](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-100), на 3.5 GHz Intel Core2 Quad q9300 требует 70 минут. Число до 60 знаков можно разложить в несколько секунд на одном из [онлайн ресурсов](http://www.numberempire.com/numberfactorizer.php), но у нас то 77!

[Открываем **другой** ресурс на котором есть возможность факторизации большого числа прямо в браузере](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) и раскладываем число на простые множители. Жмем factor и ждем...у меня на это **ушло 8 минут**. Есть еще консольные программы GGNFS и т.д. но мне подошло решение в браузере.

Еще есть встроенная в Ubuntu консольная утилита factor, с помощью нее тоже можно раскладывать числа на множители.

### Ответ

Получаем простые множители:

294214717393397322902102113848520211047 * 150756262598431142388953822991693100169

Следовательно переводим это 16-ричную систему счисления и получаем следующий код

```
dd57b184ad4252c9b59ce1b6f849fa670x716a999c7f875e33d2e211fdc5c7b489
```

Учитывайте, что вначале строки мы не ставим 0x, чтобы число залезло в 32 символа, а Python и так все поймет :)

**Подставляем в функцию..Она вернула True! Взломали!**

Comment: Превосходно !)))

Comment: 5 min 3.2s. Как техника шагнула :)

Comment: @Other главная фишка этого сайта еще в том, что алгоритм ECM который там используется вроде можно распараллелить на десятки машин, просто добавив новую кривую в браузере (more -> new curve) на другом компьютере и тогда процесс ускорится :)

Comment: Создаём ботнет и ломаем TLS :)

Comment: @Other :D но я думаю нам стоит начать с RSA-896 там дают 75k$, а нам как раз нужны деньги на этот стартап :D

Comment: А кто платить будет, конкурс вроде закрыт?

Comment: @Other эх да, RSA Factoring Challenge no longer active..а начальные инвестиции были так близки))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59280/discussion-between-other-and-firepro).

Answer (score 11):

[Бернштейн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669445/189819) от @alexolut. Ответ: `lb196fehe1ptnxn5whby37jm22qqawppD;:yr`. Уж не знаю какой там был пароль, но коллизий можно насобирать целую кучу.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int check(const char *str)
{
    uint64_t h = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        h = ((h << 5) + h) + c;

    return h == 1180004904744509286;
}

int main()
{
    char * kek = "lb196fehe1ptnxn5whby37jm22qqawppD;:yr";
    if (check(kek))
        printf("HOORAY!");
    getchar();
}
```

Более того, любые [подобные функции](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) уязвимы с точки зрения коллизий.

Теперь что вкуснее: генератор коллизий для любого данного хеша. Как пример будем использовать 1180004904744509286.

В моем решении эксплуатируется тот факт, что при возрастании входа - также линейно возрастает и выход функции. Примеры:

```
print(check(b"lb196fehe1ptnxn5whby37jm22qqawppD;:ot"))
print(check(b"lb196fehe1ptnxn5whby37jm22qqawppD;:xt"))
print(check(b"lb196fehe1ptnxn5whby37jm22qqawppD;:yt"))
print(check(b"lb196fehe1ptnxn5whby37jm22qqawppD;:ys"))
print(check(b"lb196fehe1ptnxn5whby37jm22qqawppD;:yr"))

(False, 9722971096724074958)
(False, 9722971096724075255)
(False, 9722971096724075288)
(False, 9722971096724075287)
(False, 9722971096724075286)
```

Обратите внимание - поменяли 2 с конца символ - значение хеша прыгнуло на десятки, поменяли последний символ - хеш изменился на единицу. Соответственно, мы можем "контролировать", что нам отдаст хеш функция, изменяя ввод - корреляция явная. Увеличим вход - увеличиться выход. От этого и будем исходить далее.

Без сложных подробностей просто выберем случайное число - это будет длина нашей строки для коллизии. Возьмем 20.

Инициализируем целевую строку нулями ('\x00') и будем просто поразрядно увеличивать каждый символ до тех пор, пока не попадем в цель. Мы можем без проблем позволить себе наугад брать длину строки (можно и не наугад). Генератор использует жадный алгоритм (это не самый оптимальный способ, далеко не самый быстрый, но хорош для демонстрации) - то есть каждый символ выбирается с таким расчетом, чтобы максимально приблизиться к цели, даже если в итоге это приведет в тупик. Такой подход иногда приводит к тому, что генератор зацикливается, застревает на одном месте - в таком случае встряхиваем его и генерируем случайную строку. Этот шаг назывется "мутация". Если мы попробуем генерировать случайные строки без предложенного алгоритма - это не приведет к каким-либо результатам (я пробовал) - строк слишком много, чтобы перебирать их подряд. Наконец, код (Python3) - все функции отлично мигрируют в Cython:

```
# coding: utf-8

from ctypes import c_int8
import numpy
import copy


def check(password):
    # cdef char* c_str = str
    h = 5381
    ht = 0
    modulo = 2 ** 64

    for c in password:
        # Имимтимируем C - в питоне длинные числа по умолчанию
        # Имитируем даже то, что char со знаком
        # Потребуется ли char со знако или без зависит от конкретной реализации целевой хеш-функции
        ht = (h * 33) % modulo
        h = (ht + c_int8(c).value) % modulo

    target = 1180004904744509286

    return h == target, h

TOTAL_LETTERS = 20

HASH_PAWN = bytearray(b"\0" * TOTAL_LETTERS)
HASH_GENERAL = bytearray(b"\0" * TOTAL_LETTERS)

def mutate(general):
    general = numpy.random.bytes(TOTAL_LETTERS)
    return bytearray(general)


def paste_to_c(general, total_letters):
    paster = "char kek[%d] = {" % (total_letters + 1)
    # little endian
    numbs = ", ".join([str(bt) for bt in general])
    paster += numbs + ", 0x00 };"
    return paster

target = 1180004904744509286

got_it = False
is_stuck = False
while not got_it:
    for letter_index in range(TOTAL_LETTERS):
        all_possible_values = {}
        for i in range(256):
            # ascii, можно юникод
            HASH_PAWN[letter_index] = i
            got_it, hash_value = check(bytes(HASH_PAWN))
            if got_it:
                HASH_GENERAL = copy.copy(HASH_PAWN)
            all_possible_values[i] = hash_value
        sorted_hashes = [k for k in all_possible_values.keys()]
        # Жадно отбираем победившую букву. Победила та, что ближе всех перенесла нас к цели
        sorted_hashes.sort(key=lambda asc_letter: abs(target - all_possible_values[asc_letter]))
        HASH_PAWN[letter_index] = sorted_hashes[0]
        print("%d ITERATION:" % letter_index, all_possible_values[sorted_hashes[0]])
    # Мутируем только, если результата достичь не удалось.
    # Второго шанса не предоставляем
    # Всякими штуками, типа "отбора" и "скрещивания" не занимаемся
    HASH_PAWN = mutate(HASH_PAWN)

print(bytes(HASH_GENERAL))
print(paste_to_c(HASH_GENERAL, TOTAL_LETTERS))
```

Можно запустить скрипт несколько раз - строки разные:

```
b'x<}$x2y\x8c!\x0e\xdb\xa3\xbb\xaa\x8dCOY4\xff'
char kek[21] = {120, 60, 125, 36, 120, 50, 121, 140, 33, 14, 219, 163, 187, 170, 141, 67, 79, 89, 52, 255, 0x00 };

b'fsrbY0^d\xab\x1en\x9c\x96\x08\x96\x8d\xfe\x9d\x1b\xff'
char kek[21] = {102, 115, 114, 98, 89, 48, 94, 100, 171, 30, 110, 156, 150, 8, 150, 141, 254, 157, 27, 255, 0x00 };

b'U(\xcd\x99\xc8,r\x9a\x1eB\xd8o\n\xe8\xe8\xe7T\xf5\x0e\xff'
char kek[21] = {85, 40, 205, 153, 200, 44, 114, 154, 30, 66, 216, 111, 10, 232, 232, 231, 84, 245, 14, 255, 0x00 };

b'\x86\x932\xbb\x89\xf8Bx\xbc&\x86\xe2\xe1P\xa3\xe4\x9fk\xb5\xff'
char kek[21] = {134, 147, 50, 187, 137, 248, 66, 120, 188, 38, 134, 226, 225, 80, 163, 228, 159, 107, 181, 255, 0x00 };
```

И так далее, длиной 21, 200, 15 или сколько угодно.

Comment: Поздравляю! Пароль был, конечно же, другой :) Подробнее о вычислении подходящего пароля расписать планируете?

Comment: @alexolut, планирую, но я пока сам не понял, как оно работает. Может отдельным вопросом напишу - в интернете почему-то слишком возхваляют эту функцию. Суть в том, что результат этой функции монотонно возрастает с возрастанием входных данных. То есть check("123") > check("124") > check("125"). Я почти подбором отыскал самый близкий к требуемуму результату вход - 37 нолей (\0 символов), а затем подобрал каждый байт во входных данных. Так как хеш возрастает, то я просто каждый разряд на входе инекрементировал. Опишу в любом случае подробнее

Comment: `check` возвращает булево значение, вероятно Вы имели в виду саму хэш-функцию.

Comment: @alexolut, да, саму функцию, конечно же

Comment: Ох, офигенно. Я посидел над Бернштейном вчера полчаса, но кавалерийским наскоком без теорподготовки ничего не вышло. А можно информацию о поиске хотя бы кратко дописать в ответ? Думаю, было бы интересно многим.

Answer (score 10):

Алгоритм "*7+7" от Vladimir Gamalian

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int f(char* s) {
    u_int32_t a = 0, b, i = 0;
    if (s[0] && s[1] && s[2])
        a = *(u_int32_t*)s;
    b = a;
    while (++i)
        a = a * 7 + 7;
    return a + b == 980355503;
}

int main(){
    printf("%d",f("z(!3"));
}
```

В функции берется только первые 4 байта пароля. Это значение является стартовым для цикла модификации бит и прибавляется один раз в самом конце. Причем цикл постоянно сдвигает биты влево. Отсюда следует, что младшие биты аргумента играют ключевую роль в результате, в то время, как старшие 3 ни на что не влияют.

Математик из меня никакой, так что пытаться искать математическую формулу заменяющую цикл модификации бит не стал. Пошел по пути анализа зависимости результата от аргумента. Для начала решил посмотреть повторимость значений в цикле. Для стартового значения 0 цикл выдавал результат `0xFFFFFFFF` такое же значение встретилось на итерации `1073741823`, таким образом полный цикл на 4 млрд значений не требуется, можно сократить время выполнения в 4 раза. Далее при анализе использовалась такая ускоренная функция.

Посмотрел значения итогового хеша (цикл и `a+b`) для аргументов от 0 до 16. Сразу выяснилось, что младшие 3 бита всегда 111, а четвертый бит противоположен последнему биту аргумента. Запустил на ночь печать значений функции от 0 до 8192. К утру она отработала менее чем на половину, но первых 300 значений оказалось достаточно для анализа. Сразу решил посмотреть целый последний байт хеша `AF`, оказалось, что на него оканчиваются хеши от аргументов `1A`, `3A`, `5A` и т.д. Видно, что младшие 5 бит аргумента должны быть 11010, а шестой бит нечетным. Посмотрел сразу окончание хеша `9AF`, оно оказалось для аргументов `07A`, `27A`, `47A`. И так первая буква точно `7A` (`z`), второй байт четный. Вывел значения функции от `07A` с приращением 0x200. Младшие два байта хеша `09AF` оказались для аргументов `087A`, `287A`, `487A`, `687A` и т.п. Таким же образом быстро просмотрев по несколько значений для приращений 0x2000, 0x20000, ... получал сразу по полбайта аргумента.

Comment: Эх, десять минут не успел - подходят также `z(!0x13`, `z(!S`, `z(!s`, `z(!0x93`

Comment: Супер! Даже не знаю, стоит ли теперь алгоритм модернизировать с учетом этой информации )

Answer (score 9):

**Взлом [алгоритма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669381/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8B/670254#670254) представленного Vitaly**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define M 0x2B72576B913FD740
#define S 0xB72576B913FD7400

typedef unsigned char uchar;

int check(uchar * pwd) {
    ulong s = M, i, j, k;
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(pwd); i < j; i++) for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) s = k & 0xC ? (i[pwd] & (1 << k) ? s ^ i[pwd] : s >> 1) : (*(pwd + i) & k ? s << 2 : s ^ S);
    return s == 0x0832CB347454C8AF;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("Result: %s\n", check("\x1A\xF2\x22\xD2\x32\xB6\x32\x1A\xF2\x32\x46\xF2\xD2\x30\xD2\xEA\x30\xD2\xF2\x32\xD8\xF2\x7A\xAA\x32\x80\x32\xAA\x02") ? "OK" : "FAIL");
    return 0;
}
```

При изучении алгоритма операции для начала перевел в более читаемый вид, заменил все `?` на `if`. Стало видно, что алгоритм в зависимости от конкретных бит входной строки выполняет с хешем одно из действий: "xor с S", "сдвиг вправо на 1" или "влево на 2", "xor с байтом строки". Посмотрел на это как на то, что данные действия по сути система команд, где входной байт является кодом команды, на основе которого производятся действия над хешем. Далее в тексте символы входной строки называю *команда* и обозначаю шестнадцеричным ascii кодом символа.

Вписал в `if` алгоритма `printf` печатающие, что конкретно сейчас делает *команда*. Прогнал в цикле все 255 символов и получил подобное:

```
i=0, pwd[i]=1A, bit 0 s^S               9C5721D282C2A340
i=0, pwd[i]=1A, bit 1 s^S               2B72576B913FD740
i=0, pwd[i]=1A, bit 2 s<<2              ADC95DAE44FF5D00
i=0, pwd[i]=1A, bit 3 s<<2              B72576B913FD7400
i=0, pwd[i]=1A, bit 4 s^pwd             B72576B913FD741A
i=0, pwd[i]=1A, bit 5 s>>1              5B92BB5C89FEBA0D
i=0, pwd[i]=1A, bit 6 s>>1              2DC95DAE44FF5D06
i=0, pwd[i]=1A, bit 7 s>>1              16E4AED7227FAE83
1A: 16E4AED7227FAE83
```

Тут мы видим, что *команда* 1A выполняет два "xor S" (а два xor с одним числом дают нулевой результат), сдвигают хеш на 4 бита влево, делают xor с входным байтом (т.е. с кодом *команды* 1A) и сдвигают на 3 бита вправо. Примерно половина *команд* выполняют нечетное количество "xor S" и в итоге безнадежно "портят" хеш. Еще 1/8 *команд* не делают ничего. А вот все остальные позволяют манипулировать битами младшего байта и выполнять сдвиги. Прогнал те же 255 значений через функцию выполняющую *команду* над числами "все FFFF", "0" и "F123..EF" получил распечатку вида (тестовые числа, код *комадны*, мои комментарии):

```
0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 0000000000000000 0123456789ABCDEF 02 <<4 >>4
0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 0000000000000000 0F123456789ABCDE 04 >>4
1FFFFFFFFFFFFF7F 0000000000000080 1E2468ACF135793D 80 >>3 0x80  10000000
1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFD 0000000000000003 02468ACF13579BDD 1A  <<4 ^0x1A >>3  00011010
3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFC 0000000000000000 048D159E26AF37BC 32 <<2 (<<4, >>2)
3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 0000000000000000 3C48D159E26AF37B 30 >>2
```

Комментарии дописывал по ходу работы, читая первую распечатку с точными действиями.
Взял требуемое число `0x0832CB347454C8AF` в двоичном виде: `0000100000110010110010110011010001110100010101001100100010101111`. Стартовое число `M` оканчивается на `1000000`, это стало отправной точкой для формирования нужного результата. Постепенно дописывал к нему/модифицировал несколько бит в конец, добавляя в входную строку *команду*. Очень напрягало, что в системе команд отсутствуют сдвиги на нечетное количество бит без выполнения побочных действий вроде "xor код-команды". Это сильно усложняло жизнь. Процесс проходил в текстовом файле (разумеется с добалением каждой *команды* в отладочную программу для проверки результата), примерно так:

```
1A: ........................................................10000011
F2: ....................................................100000110000
22: ...................................................1000001101000
D2: ................................................1000001100101001
------
32: .....10000011001011001011001101000111010001010100110000000101100
80: ........10000011001011001011001101000111010001010100110010000101
32: ......1000001100101100101100110100011101000101010011001000010100
AA: 0110100000110010110010110011010001110100010101001100100010101111
02: 0000100000110010110010110011010001110100010101001100100010101111
```

Так по битику и родилось нужное значение ...

Comment: Я уж думал, что никто не взломает. Алгоритм, на самом деле, слабый, просто немного запутанный обилием операций. ;)

Comment: Ничего себе анализ! Круто, что сказать.

Answer (score 8):

Взлом [разминочного алгоритма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670439/16416) от Firepro

Для интереса решил попробовать тупой перебор на поиск. Что бы поиск шел быстрее, поставил ограничение на символы до 5000.

```
int check = 766862343;
int hash = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++) 
{
    for (int ch = 0; ch < 5000; ch++)
    {
        if ((hash ^ (hash * 23 + ch)) == check)
            Console.WriteLine(hash + ":" + ch);
    }
    hash++;
}
```

Где-то через 20 минут на 32 000 000 получаем пару сотен коллизий.

```
32348910:4999
32348911:4975
32348912:4967
32348913:4943
32348914:4919
...
```

Далее поиск идет быстрее, выбираем понравившуюся пару и повторяем все до тех пор, пока не получим коллизию со значением менее вместимости типа Char. Поскольку их было очень много и поиск шел быстро, я даже потратил время на поиск простого пароля из нормальных символов.

```
32349132 : 119 w
1446183 : 106 j
65727 : 111 o
2970 : 79 O
85 U : 1068 Ь
```

Один из вариантов пароля **UЬOojw**

Comment: Круто! Спасибо! Я так и хотел, чтобы его быстро взломали  коллизиями, подбором и показали разбор :) Ответ был: likeSO

Comment: Чуть-чуть не успел) Первую `'r'` подобрал ручками, потом на 16-ядерном серваке запустил параллельный перебор остальных 5 символов от `0x00` до `0xFF`. Где-то минуты через 2 сыпятся ответы. Например: `"r\xA0\x0F\xD5\xFA\x27"`

Comment: @Андрей, у меня увы только рабочий ПК, а там еще вторая хеш функция от  Firepro и просто так я думаю ее уже не взять.

Answer (score 8):

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669698/10105

Пароль: `"My_Extra_Fix_Passord-(836199132"`.

Глядя в алгоритм, видно, что функцию сравнения использует лишь `partition3`. Эта функция сравнения «выплёвывает» в вывод 75% символов партиционируемого отрезка, а в остальные позиции кладёт символ, по которому ведётся партиционирование. Порядок сравнения символов в партиционируемом отрезке — строго от начала к концу. Кроме того, в функции `Array::qsort` видно, что партиционирование всегда ведётся по первому символу. Смотря в кодовое слово

```
My_EMtraMFixMPasMordM(83M199M32EE-(8E619E132-(83-199-328861
```

замечаем повторяющийся через 4 символ `M`. Это вывод одного и того же, первого партиционирования по всей длине пароля (т. к. больше символ `M` ни в левой, и в правой группе не встретится). Итак, наш пароль имеет вид

```
My_E?tra?Fix?Pas?ord?(83?199?32E
```

причём последние символы до ? могут и не присутствовать в пароле. Предположим, что длина ровно 32 символа, то есть строка заканчивается на `E`. Модифицируем функцию `qsort`, чтобы она выводила свои промежуточные результаты:

```ruby
def qsort(&block)
  return self.dup if size <=1
  c,l,r = partition3 {|x| block.call(first,x)}
  puts("partition, pivot = #{first}, l=#{l.join}, r=#{r.join}, c=#{c.join}")
  l.qsort(&block) + c + r.qsort(&block)
end

$z = 'My_EMtraMFixMPasMordM(83M199M32EE-(8E619E132-(83-199-3288619813236113211199yyxtry_ixyPasyord_xtr__ix_Pas_ordxtraxxasxordtraitssotdrarassrrdaaaodiodss'

def check(password)
  z = $z
  h = g_c(password)
  i = 0; // увеличиваем, когда есть общий кусок
  if (h[0...i] == z[0...i])
    puts("starting #{i} symbols match")
  else
    puts("starting #{i} symbols DIFFER")
  end
  puts(h[i..-1])
  puts(z[i..-1])
  puts("diff = #{dist(h, z)}")
  h == z
end
```

(функция `dist` считает количество несовпадающих символов в двух строках)

Получаем первую партицию:

```
pivot = M, l=EF(8319932E, r=y_~tra~ix~Pas~ord~~~, c=M
```

Следующее партиционирование должно быть, согласно алгоритму, у последовательности `EF(8319932E`, и вывод должен тогда иметь вид `EF(8E199E...`. Но в реальной строке `F` отсутствует, а на его месте `-`: `E-(8E...`. Спасти ситуацию, вставив другие символы на место `~`, не получается. Это означает, что предположение о длине строки неверно. Пробуем длину на единицу меньше.

```
My_E?tra?Fix?Pas?ord?(83?199?32
```

Первая партиция

```
pivot = M, l=EF(8319932, r=y_~tra~ix~Pas~ord~~~, c=M
```

Вывод второй партиции выглядит как `EE(83E...`, из которых второй и третий экземпляр `E` означает элемент, *по* которому проводилось партиционирование. Фактически мы видим `EE-(8E...`, это означает, что один из символов `~` перед скобкой должен быть на самом деле `-`, чтобы попасть в партиционируемую группу (а остальные больше `M`). В первых двух позициях получается плохой результат, а в третей `EE-(8E`, как и нужно.

Далее, в следующем партиционировании

```
pivot = E, l=-(8319932, r=F, c=E
```

у нас получается группа `-(8E199E2`, а в реальности `-(8E619E132`, что даёт хвост пароля `(836199132`. С таким паролем у нас уже выходит верная первая половина кодового слова, отвечающего за первую партицию:

```
My_EMtraMFixMPasMordM(83M199M32EE-(8E619E132-(83-199-3288619813236113211199
```

Переходим ко второй половине. Партиционирование `y_~tra~ixPas~ord~`

```
pivot = y, l=_traixPasord, r=~~~~, c=y
```

выдаёт строку `yy~try~`, а должно получиться `yyxtry_`. Похоже на то, что  вместо первой `~` у нас `x`, а вместо второй — `_`. Получаем уточнённый пароль `My_Extra_Fix-Pas~ord~(836199132`. Дальнейший вывод `yas~yrd~`, а должен быть `yPasyord`, это значит, что у нас сдвиг на один символ, а значит, предположение о том, где находится `-`, было неверно. Из двух вариантов `My_Extra_Fix~Pas-ord~(836199132` и `My_Extra_Fix~Pas~ord-(836199132` второй производит намного более длинную совпадающую строку.

В этой точке осталось разгадать два символа. Проще всего их сбрутфорсить, но исходя из человеческого фактора, на месте второй тильды должен бы быть `s` или `w`. Поскольку у нас нигде не встречается буква `w`, пробуем букву `s`. На место последнего символа перебором получаем `_`.

Всё!

Comment: Теперь я знаю что кролики не только пуфыстые, но и хакеры :)

Comment: Браво! А можно уточнить сколько времени потребовалось?

Comment: @Чад: Довольно много. Но большую часть времени я боролся с собственным незнанием языка (trailing closure — это круто, да). Я сначала пошёл по ложному пути, подумал, что нужно 32 символа, и это привело к логическому противоречию, из которого я долго не мог выпутаться. В общей сложности наверное часа два вчера и час сегодня. // Спасибо!

Comment: @Other: Спасибо!

Answer (score 8):

**Взлом [алгоритма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670655/198501)  от Eanmos**

Алгоритм действительно очень простой.

Первое, что я сделал это нашел строку на которой функция дает значение чуть большее, чем нужно:

```
wchar_t a[] = {
0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 
0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 
0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 
0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 
0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0x6FFF,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0};
```

А далее перебирается первый аргумент от 1 до 0xFFFF.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int h(wchar_t* s)
{
    uint64_t h = 0;
    if (wcslen(s) < 60) return 0;
    for (uint64_t i = 1; *s++; h += *s*i + *(s-1) * i, i++);
    return h; // == 0x75F00B5; // 123666613
}

int f(wchar_t* s)
{
    uint64_t h = 0;
    if (wcslen(s) < 60) return 0;
    for (uint64_t i = 1; *s++; h += *s*i + *(s-1) * i, i++);
    return h == 0x75F00B5;
}

int main() {
    wchar_t a[] = {
    0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 
    0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 
    0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 
    0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 
    0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0x6FFF,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0};
    for (int i = 1; i < 0xFFFF; i++) {
        a[0] = i;
        if (h(a) == 123666613) {
            cout << i << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << f(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Ответ:

```
wchar_t a[] = {
56656, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 
0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 
0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 
0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 
0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0x6FFF,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0};
```

Comment: Найденный Вами пароль довольно симпатично выглядит, по сравнению с исходным: `"$1@Qdy}©Äáઐૹ夑婀孱岤巙弐恉憄拁搀敁暄柉椐橙殤泱湀澑烤爹玐瓩癄瞡鷑귩뻉삄임齤ꃹ纐葀薱钉鞙湀範錄苑玐躁訐暄䄁钉䈄钉紩烤"`))

Comment: @Eanmos не подскажите где вы такую строку сгенерировали?

Comment: https://unicode-table.com/ru/ . Брал все знаки, из которых можно извлечь квадратный корень. Просто вбиваешь в поиск что-то типа: `Dec: 121`. Потом увидел, что `sqrt` использовать нельзя. Алгоритм изменился, а пароль остался)

Comment: @Eanmos sqrt если что можно легко реализовать: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: спасибо, действительно довольно простой метод.

Answer (score 6):

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669774/182935

Ответ:

```
int P[2] = {0x9FC1C7F6,0};
    char *cc = (char *)&P;

Переводить в символы не стал).

В коде баг или как? Часть с использованием `m[]` не работает (xor от него равен 0)
```

Comment: Проверил и внёс в таблицу. :)

Comment: Если перевести в строку получится что-то типа этого: ƒ┴╟÷

Comment: Рассчитывал в качестве входных данных обычную строку. Хорошо, учту на будущее. Код с использованием `m[]` работает. Итерация получается такая: 2C4EC9C4 - AA7720AE - 9FC1C7F6 - 7720AEAA.

Answer (score 3):

**Взлом еще одного [алгоритма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/669381/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%8B/670094#670094) представленного Vitaly**

Пароль:

```
AeMzQ8oZk31W4B(L\1Uh$,9m</cZeQ"LBygghYTC7QQMwY8otyMNobKExaZ181d<@U'S{@7cNqJZ
```

Тут все оказалось просто, символ в строке зависит только от следующего за ним. Сделал программку, пробежавшуюся по строке задом наперед и просто подбирающую подходящий символ. Небольшое осложнение - некоторые символы не могут встречаться перед определенными. Поэтому программа подобрав один символ запоминает точку на которой она остановилась и в случае если далее по строке подходящего варианта не нашлось, возвращается обратно и находит другой подходящий символ.

Программа декодер отрабатывает менее чем за секунду:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char uchar;
uchar need[]="Tp9?k=HDN&nD{9 ~JzUYG3h>lF {`> K<% pm~J>y E=2B=y+<x+nf@*%kDZ;z/'WYbWOk'usw>Z";

int check(uchar * pwd) {
    uchar * a = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~";
    int d = strlen(a), i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = strlen(pwd); i < j; i++) {
        if (strchr(a, pwd[i]) == NULL) pwd[i] = a[pwd[i] % d];
        if (i > 0) pwd[i - 1] = a[(((pwd[i - 1] ^ pwd[i]) << 1) * pwd[i]) % d];
    }
    return !strcmp(pwd, need);
}
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    uchar pwd[3];
    int len=strlen(need);
    uchar * pwd2 = calloc(len+5, sizeof(char));
    int i;
    memset(pwd2,31,255);
    pwd2[len-1]=need[len-1]; pwd2[len]=0;
    pwd[2]=0;
    for(i=len-2;i>=0;i--) {
      char c,found;
      found=0;
xx:
      pwd[1]=pwd2[i+1];
      for(pwd2[i]++;pwd2[i]<0x7F;pwd2[i]++) {
       pwd[0]=pwd2[i];
       check(pwd);
       if(pwd[0]==need[i]) { found++; break; }
      }
     if(!found) {
      pwd2[i]=31;
      if(++i>len-2) break;
      goto xx;
     }
   }
   printf("\n%s\n",pwd2);
   printf("Result: %s\n", check(pwd2) ? "OK" : "FAIL");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Хм, у меня проверка пароля падает с сегфолтом на MSVC. И на ideone тоже: http://ideone.com/Qz014S. Может быть, неправильно перевёл?

Comment: Хотя заставить функцию упасть тоже считается взломом по идее.

Comment: @VladD Я пока отлаживался то же на это натыкался. Функция автора изменяет строку вызывающей программы, поэтому как константу в кавычках ее нельзя передавать. Надо подготовить буфер в ОЗУ и записать тестуруемую строку туда. Данное падение как взлом не считал, т.к. в чате оговаривали, что подача незаписываемой памяти программе вроде как внешнее воздействие

Comment: @VladD http://ideone.com/PXfM3b

Comment: Ну, вообще-то в условии имелось в виду, что память должна быть доступна для _чтения_, а не для записи. Хотя, раз функция хочет на вход именно `char*`, а не `const char*`, то конечно надо передавать ей символы, в которые можно писать, да.

Comment: Странно, не падало у меня. Правда, под виндой не тестил. Ладно, раз падает, тогда ничего не поделать.

Comment: @Vitaly А вы свой check() вызывали передавая строку в кавычках, а не из буфера ? Речь то только об этом, и в общем то это не критично

Comment: Да, я вызывал программу из командной строки и передавал ей обычную строку. Скажу больше, там были только латинские буквы обоих регистров и цифры. Собственно, как и все остальные программы, которые я присылал.

Comment: @Vitaly Значит мой подборщик нашел немного другое значение, присутствуют кавычки и обратная косая :) в принципе его несложно модифицировать, что бы получить все возможные подходящие ключи.

Answer (score 3):

Действительно, было бы смешно не взломать [Алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/672396)

Я конечно не очень шарю в С++, да и фиг его знает какой тип подкинет компилятор вместо auto для h. Скорее всего в вашем случае он подставил тип int. И коллизий будет много уже при длине слова 2, например 237 и 84 символы. И даже если он каким-то чудом определит h как long, то тот же вагон коллизий случится на словах в три символа, например 187, 44, 77

Подходит, например, пароль `"yBw"`.

Comment: А пароль-то какой?

Comment: По номерам символов не восстановишь?)) Например: "yBw"

Comment: Ну, формальное требование к взлому — он должен содержать либо пароль, либо код, генерирующий пароль.

Comment: Да уж, коллизий там должно было быть и правда много. Но не из-за разрядности типа данных, причина в другом. Жаль конечно, что коллизии были найдены без криптоанализа :-)